# Most efficient way to return list from a groupby

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a 130M rows dataframe, here is a sample:

```
    id              id2     date         value
0   33208381500016  1927637 2014-07-31   120.0
1   77874276700016  3418498 2014-11-22   10.5
2   77874276700016  1174018 2014-11-22   8.4
3   77874276700016  1174018 2014-11-20   1.4
4   77874276700016  1643839 2014-06-27   4.2
5   77874276700016  1972929 2014-06-27   6.7
6   77874276700016  1972929 2014-06-27   12.7
7   77874276700016  1588191 2014-02-20   123.4
8   77874276700016  1966627 2014-02-20   973.1
9   77874276700016  1830252 2014-02-20   0.5
```

I need to perform a `groupby` on this dataframe (called `data`). For a simple `groupby` like a `sum` no problem:

```
data[['id','value']].groupby('id',as_index=False).sum()
time: 11.19s
```

But now I need to retrieve the list of values in another column (or it's length). This following code works, but takes ages, it there a more efficient way to do it?

```
temp = data[['id','date','id2']].drop_duplicates()
temp.groupby('id',as_index = False).agg({'date': lambda x: set(x.tolist()),'id2':lambda x: len(set(x.tolist()))})
time: 159s
```

First question:

Is there a more efficient way to count the number of unique `id2` for every `id`, but still using this groupby? What I mean is I don't want to split the two groupbys as it will probably take longer (performing one groupby with 2 aggregations takes approximately 1.5 times one sole grouby).

Second question:

Is there a more efficient way to retrieve the list of unique dates? I know it has been addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) but I can't simply use `.apply(list)`.

Comment: You don't appear to have a `value` in your sample df...

Comment: @JonClements Well, indeed I simplified it too much. Fixed it

Comment: For a start - `set` will take an iterable so you can do `set(x)` instead of `set(x.tolist())` that'll save some overhead... how does that affect your timings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the unique dates, use [`SeriesGroupBy.unique()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html). To count the number of unique `id2` in each group, use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html).

```
temp = data[['id', 'date', 'id2']].drop_duplicates()
temp.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': 'unique', 'id2': 'nunique'})
```

Not dropping duplicates beforehand may be faster — pandas only has to iterate once over all your data instead of twice.

```
data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': 'unique', 'id2': 'nunique'})
```

EDIT:

Here are some benchmarks. Interestingly, `SeriesGroupBy.unique()` and `SeriesGroupBy.nunique()` do not seem to be faster than using sets. But not dropping duplicates before is.

```
import io

import pandas as pd

raw = io.StringIO("""\
id              id2     date         value
0   33208381500016  1927637 2014-07-31   120.0
1   77874276700016  3418498 2014-11-22   10.5
2   77874276700016  1174018 2014-11-22   8.4
3   77874276700016  1174018 2014-11-20   1.4
4   77874276700016  1643839 2014-06-27   4.2
5   77874276700016  1972929 2014-06-27   6.7
6   77874276700016  1972929 2014-06-27   12.7
7   77874276700016  1588191 2014-02-20   123.4
8   77874276700016  1966627 2014-02-20   973.1
9   77874276700016  1830252 2014-02-20   0.5
""")

data = pd.read_csv(raw, delim_whitespace=True)

def using_sets_drop_then_group():
    temp = data[['id', 'date', 'id2']].drop_duplicates()
    temp.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': lambda x: set(x),
                                            'id2': lambda x: len(set(x))})

def using_sets_drop_just_group():
    data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': lambda x: set(x),
                                            'id2': lambda x: len(set(x))})

def using_unique_drop_then_group():
    temp = data[['id', 'date', 'id2']].drop_duplicates()
    temp.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': 'unique', 'id2': 'nunique'})

def using_unique_just_group():
    data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': 'unique', 'id2': 'nunique'})

%timeit using_sets_drop_then_group()   # => 100 loops, best of 3: 4.82 ms per loop
%timeit using_sets_drop_just_group()   # => 100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
%timeit using_unique_drop_then_group() # => 100 loops, best of 3: 5.14 ms per loop
%timeit using_unique_just_group()      # => 100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

In a comment, @ptrj suggests `SeriesGroupBy.unique()` and `SeriesGroupBy.nunique()` may be faster if dates are converted to `datetime64`. Alas it does not seem to be the case, at least for this small sample of data.

```
data['parsed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

def using_sets_and_datetime64():
    data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'parsed_date': lambda x: set(x),
                                            'id2': lambda x: len(set(x))})

def using_unique_and_datetime64():
    data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'parsed_date': 'unique',
                                            'id2': 'nunique'})

%timeit using_sets_and_datetime64()    # => 100 loops, best of 3: 3.2 ms per loop
%timeit using_unique_and_datetime64()  # => 100 loops, best of 3: 3.53 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

@MaxU's suggestion of concatenating 100,000 copies of the sample data indeed leads to `SeriesGroupBy.unique()` and `SeriesGroupBy.nunique()` outperforming `set`.

```
large_data = pd.concat([data] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

def using_sets():
    large_data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': lambda x: set(x),
                                                  'id2': lambda x: len(set(x))})

def using_unique():
    large_data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'date': 'unique',
                                                  'id2': 'nunique'})

def using_sets_and_datetime64():
    large_data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'parsed_date': lambda x: set(x),
                                                  'id2': lambda x: len(set(x))})

def using_unique_and_datetime64():
    large_data.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg({'parsed_date': 'unique',
                                                  'id2': 'nunique'})

%timeit using_sets()                   # => 1 loops, best of 3: 295 ms per loop
%timeit using_unique()                 # => 1 loops, best of 3: 327 ms per loop
%timeit using_sets_and_datetime64()    # => 1 loops, best of 3: 5.02 s per loop
%timeit using_unique_and_datetime64()  # => 1 loops, best of 3: 248 ms per loop
```

Comment: IIUC you're using dates as strings. `unique` may be faster then `set` if dates are converted to a `datetime64` type (and with larger data).

Comment: Timeit using 1M rows DF: `data = pd.concat([data] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)`, but don't remove duplicates because it'll be too small... The `set(...)` solution should be much slower...