# how extract a vector from groupby pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame using pandas:

```
one    two  three

 1      2    1 
 4      1    1
 2      2    1
 3      1    2
 20     2    2
```

Now, I would extract the a vector by grouping 'three'.
Basically, I should obtain vectors from the 'two' column based on grouping "three":

```
groupby('three')
a=[2,1,2]
b=[1,2]
```

thanks a lot

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
s = df.groupby('three')['two'].apply(list)
print (s)
three
1    [2, 1, 2]
2       [1, 2]
Name: two, dtype: object

a = s.loc[1]
b = s.loc[2]
print (a)
[2, 1, 2]

print (b)
[1, 2]
```

If need nested lists:

```
L = df.groupby('three')['two'].apply(list).tolist()
print (L)
[[2, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Another possible solutions:

```
L = [list(x) for i, x in df.groupby('three')['two']]
print (L)
[[2, 1, 2], [1, 2]]

L = [x.tolist() for i, x in tuple(df.groupby('three')['two'])]
print (L)
[[2, 1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Perfect, great. But, how can i use the result, it is a DataFrame? basically, how can i manage the resulting vectors?

Comment: What does it mean manage? output is [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series)

Comment: Thank a lot. I have putted the output within columns in a DataFrame, now I would plot with plot.box just the arrays that we have obtained, could you please help me? Obtaining a plot as a sequence of box plot

Comment: Glad can help you, nice day!

Comment: Thank a lot. I have putted the output within columns in a DataFrame, now I would plot with plot.box just the arrays that we have obtained, could you please help me? Obtaining a plot as a sequence of box plot

Comment: Now I am only on phone, so it is problematic answer. The best is check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots), if still problem try ask another question. Dont forget add data sample, code what you try and describe desired output.