# How to groupby by a column and return the values of other columns as lists in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing trouble clubbing the values of a column together and retaining the respective values of other columns. I would like to do something similar to this: [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby#)

But instead, I want the list/dictionary (preferably latter) to contain values of multiple columns.
Example for this dataframe:

df:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
A      xyz     1
A      pqr     2
B      xyz     2
B      pqr     3
B      lmn     1
C      pqr     2
```

I want something like-

```
A {'xyz':1, 'pqr': 2}
B {'xyz':2, 'pqr': 3, 'lmn': 1}
C {'pqr':2}
```

I tried doing

```
df.groupby('Col1')[['Col2', 'Col3']].apply(list)
```

which is a variant of the solution mentioned in the linked post, but isn't giving me the result I need.

From that point on, I would also like to transform it into a dataframe of the form:

```
  xyz  pqr  lmn
A  1    2    NaN
B  2    3    1
C  NaN  2    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='Col1',columns='Col2',values='Col3')
print (df)
Col2  lmn  pqr  xyz
Col1               
A     NaN  2.0  1.0
B     1.0  3.0  2.0
C     NaN  2.0  NaN
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].unstack()
print (df)

Col2  lmn  pqr  xyz
Col1               
A     NaN  2.0  1.0
B     1.0  3.0  2.0
C     NaN  2.0  NaN
```

but if:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means duplicates, need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or aggregate with `groupby` by `mean` (can be changed to `sum`, `median`), and last reshape by `unstack`:

```
print (df)
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A  xyz     1 <-same A, xyz
1    A  xyz     5 <-same A, xyz
2    A  pqr     2
3    B  xyz     2
4    B  pqr     3
5    B  lmn     1
6    C  pqr     2

df = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].mean().unstack()
print (df)
Col2  lmn  pqr  xyz
Col1               
A     NaN  2.0  3.0 (1+5)/2 = 3
B     1.0  3.0  2.0
C     NaN  2.0  NaN
```

EDIT:

For check all duplicates by `Col1` and `Col2`:

```
print (df[df.duplicated(subset=['Col1','Col2'], keep=False)])
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A  xyz     1
1    A  xyz     5
```

EDIT1:

If need only first row if duplicates:

```
df = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].first().unstack()
print (df)
Col2  lmn  pqr  xyz
Col1               
A     NaN  2.0  1.0
B     1.0  3.0  2.0
C     NaN  2.0  NaN
```

Or better first remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then use first or second solution:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Col1','Col2'])
df = df.pivot(index='Col1',columns='Col2',values='Col3')
print (df)
Col2  lmn  pqr  xyz
Col1               
A     NaN  2.0  1.0
B     1.0  3.0  2.0
C     NaN  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: There has to be duplicates, because error. At least one. I add code for check it.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the ValueError. However, I cannot use the mean approach that you mentioned because the values are categorical variables. Is there a way I can just use the first row it encounters (for example ignore the row A,xyz,5)?

Answer (score 1):

What you want in the end is a pivot table.

`df.pivot_table(index='Col1',columns='Col2',values='Col3')`

look up the documentation for more options.

Comment: I get this when I run it on my dataset: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Answer (score 1):

Neither one of these are `pandas` only solutions.  I provided them because I find exploring alternatives fun.  The `bincount` base solution is very fast but less transparent.

**Creative Solution 1**
*`collections.defaultdict` and dictionary comprehension*

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
[d[c2].setdefault(c1, c3) for i, c1, c2, c3 in df.itertuples()];
pd.DataFrame(d)

   lmn  pqr  xyz
A  NaN    2  1.0
B  1.0    3  2.0
C  NaN    2  NaN
```

---

**Creative Solution 2**
*`pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`*

```
f1, u1 = pd.factorize(df.Col1.values)
f2, u2 = pd.factorize(df.Col2.values)
w = df.Col3.values

n, m = u1.size, u2.size

v = np.bincount(f1 * n + f2, w, n * m).reshape(n, m)
pd.DataFrame(np.ma.array(v, mask=v == 0), u1, u2)

   lmn  pqr  xyz
A  NaN    2  1.0
B  1.0    3  2.0
C  NaN    2  NaN
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.pivot(index='Col1',columns='Col2',values='Col3')
%timeit df.set_index(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].unstack()
%timeit df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].mean().unstack()
%timeit df.pivot_table(index='Col1',columns='Col2',values='Col3')

%%timeit
d = defaultdict(dict)
[d[c2].setdefault(c1, c3) for i, c1, c2, c3 in df.itertuples()];
pd.DataFrame(d)

%%timeit
f1, u1 = pd.factorize(df.Col1.values)
f2, u2 = pd.factorize(df.Col2.values)
w = df.Col3.values

n, m = u1.size, u2.size

v = np.bincount(f1 * n + f2, w, n * m).reshape(n, m)
pd.DataFrame(np.ma.array(v, mask=v == 0), u1, u2)
```

*small data*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.17 ms per loop

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop

1000 loops, best of 3: 420 µs per loop
```

*medium data*

```
from string import ascii_letters
l = list(ascii_letters)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Col1=np.random.choice(l, 10000),
        Col2=np.random.choice(l, 10000),
        Col3=np.random.randint(10, size=10000)
    )).drop_duplicates(['Col1', 'Col2'])

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.17 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.89 ms per loop

100 loops, best of 3: 5.6 ms per loop

1000 loops, best of 3: 549 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is awesome @piRSquared! Only one minor pointer: I cannot/should not compute the mean for Col3 because it is a categorical variable.

Comment: @RijulMagu assuming your combinations of `Col1` and `Col2` are unique, this is not an issue.  However, if they are not unique, what is your preference for aggregating the multiple instances?  You must decide as your final dataframe consist of one cell per unique combination of `Col1` and `Col2`.  That one cell must contain an aggregation or summary of all possible instances.  Do you want the last one?, The first?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to decide (in the original dataset, where duplicates occur, one is the "correct" row and the other is forged but it's extremely difficult to tell which one's which). Therefore, I'm using the first one.

Comment: If that is the assumption, simply start with a filter `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Col1', 'Col2'])`  This will keep the first instance of each unique combination.  Then proceed with the rest of the solution.