# Create columns of lists from DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, list, dataframe, group-by

I would like to create a groupby dataframe and group row in multiple lists :
I have the following dataframe :

```
list_date    = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5]
list_request = [2,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]
list_users   = [1,3,7,1,7,3,4,9,7,9]
list_count   = [1,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,1,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':list_date,'request':list_request,'users':list_users, 'count':list_count})

count  date  request  users
0      1     1        2      1
1      1     1        2      3
2      2     2        2      7
3      3     2        3      1
4      1     2        3      7
5      3     3        2      3
6      1     3        3      4
7      2     3        3      9
8      1     4        3      7
9      1     5        3      9
```

and I want to have the following result (grouping by ['date','request']):

```
count       date  request   users
0  [1, 1]     1        2  [1, 3]
1     [2]     2        2     [7]
2  [3, 1]     2        3  [1, 7]
3     [3]     3        2     [3]
4  [1, 2]     3        3  [4, 9]
5     [1]     4        3     [7]
6     [1]     5        3     [9]
```

If I use the solution here : [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)
I can create 1 list but how can I create 2 lists at the same time ? 
Something like :

```
df = df.groupby(['date','request'])['users','count'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

And I need something efficient as in reality I have millions of rows...

Thank you!

Comment: What are you grouping by?

Comment: I am grouping by date and request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `pd.Series` and then rename your columns:

```
In [299]: df.groupby(['date', 'request']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series((x['count'].tolist(), x['users'].tolist()))).reset_index().rename(columns={0 : 'count', 1 : 'users'})
Out[299]: 
   date  request   count   users
0     1        2  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1     2        2     [2]     [7]
2     2        3  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3     3        2     [3]     [3]
4     3        3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5     4        3     [1]     [7]
6     5        3     [1]     [9]
```

Another solution is applying list with `df.apply`:

```
In [364]: grouped_df = df.groupby(['date', 'request'])

In [365]: pd.DataFrame({ 'count' : grouped_df['count'].apply(list), 'users' : grouped_df['users'].apply(list) }).reset_index() #, columns=['count', 'users'])
Out[365]: 
   date  request   count   users
0     1        2  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1     2        2     [2]     [7]
2     2        3  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3     3        2     [3]     [3]
4     3        3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5     4        3     [1]     [7]
6     5        3     [1]     [9]
```

---

Better solutions may be seen here (I asked a question): [Converting each grouped column in DataFrameGroupBy object to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336273/converting-each-grouped-column-in-dataframegroupby-object-to-a-list/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you COLDSPEED

Comment: @eleanor Glad to help. Came up with an alternative. May be faster.

Comment: @eleanor I am new to pandas so excuse my ignorance. For better solutions to your problem look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336273/converting-each-grouped-column-in-dataframegroupby-object-to-a-list/