# Converting each grouped column in DataFrameGroupBy object to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5],
    'request':[2,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3],
    'users':[1,3,7,1,7,3,4,9,7,9],
    'count':[1,1,2,3,1,3,1,2,1,1]
})

df

   count  date  request  users
0      1     1        2      1
1      1     1        2      3
2      2     2        2      7
3      3     2        3      1
4      1     2        3      7
5      3     3        2      3
6      1     3        3      4
7      2     3        3      9
8      1     4        3      7
9      1     5        3      9
```

The idea is to group by `count` and `date`, and convert every other column to a list of grouped values. I thought this would be as simple as calling `dfgp.agg` but it is not.

This is what I want to do:

```
   date  request   count   users
0     1        2  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1     2        2     [2]     [7]
2     2        3  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3     3        2     [3]     [3]
4     3        3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5     4        3     [1]     [7]
6     5        3     [1]     [9]
```

This is how I have done it:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['date', 'request'])

df_new = pd.DataFrame({ 'count' : grouped_df['count'].apply(list), 'users' : grouped_df['users'].apply(list) }).reset_index()
```

It works but I believe there has to be a better way... one that can work on *all* columns in the grouped object. For example, I should group by just `date` and the solution should work. My solution will rely on hardcoding the columns, that I dislike doing, so it will fail in this instance.

This is a something that has been bothering me. It should be an obvious solution but I cannot find it. Is there a better way?

---

<sub>Calling all my Pandas MVPs...</sub>

Comment: Is `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()])` okay, list of lists though?

Comment: @JohnGalt Haha that seems too easy... no... I am looking for a list, not list of lists :)

Comment: At the moment, this hack would `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).apply(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)` work. But seems clunky.

Comment: Standard Warning: Storing list-likes in cells is not an intended use case for pandas and is poorly supported.  By doing so you lose all of the speedups associated with pandas, and will essentially be operating at pure python speed when dealing with those columns.  There is usually a better data representation that can be used.

Comment: @root Yes. The use cases of such an operation are far and few, but they do exist. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even Better Answer**
*Find where duplicates happen, split and filter accordingly*

```
dups = df.duplicated(['request', 'date'], 'last').values
i = np.where(~dups[:-1])[0] + 1
r, d, c, u = (df[c].values for c in df)

d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([r[~dups], d[~dups]]), columns=['request', 'date'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([np.split(c, i), np.split(u, i)]), columns=['count', 'users'])

d1.join(d2)

   date  requeset   count   users
0     1         2  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1     2         2     [2]     [7]
2     2         3  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3     3         2     [3]     [3]
4     3         3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5     4         3     [1]     [7]
6     5         3     [1]     [9]
```

---

**Answer I feel good about!**
Yay! `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

s = df.set_index(['date', 'request']).stack()
[d[k].append(v) for k, v in s.iteritems()];

pd.Series(d).unstack().rename_axis(['date', 'requeset']).reset_index()

   date  requeset   count   users
0     1         2  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1     2         2     [2]     [7]
2     2         3  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3     3         2     [3]     [3]
4     3         3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5     4         3     [1]     [7]
6     5         3     [1]     [9]
```

---

**Old Answer**

```
f = lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.T.tolist(), x.columns)
df.groupby(['request', 'date'])[['count', 'users']].apply(f).reset_index()

   request  date   count   users
0        2     1  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1        2     2     [2]     [7]
2        2     3     [3]     [3]
3        3     2  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
4        3     3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5        3     4     [1]     [7]
6        3     5     [1]     [9]
```

---

**Frustration Answer!**
Shoehorning `agg`

```
from ast import liter_eval

df.groupby(['request', 'date']).agg(
    lambda x: str(list(x))
).applymap(literal_eval).reset_index()

   request  date   count   users
0        2     1  [1, 1]  [1, 3]
1        2     2     [2]     [7]
2        2     3     [3]     [3]
3        3     2  [3, 1]  [1, 7]
4        3     3  [1, 2]  [4, 9]
5        3     4     [1]     [7]
6        3     5     [1]     [9]
```

Comment: Another solution I attempted, but didn't mention here was `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series((x['count'].tolist(), x['users'].tolist()))).reset_index()`. This is definitely along the same lines but much cleaner. I like this.

Comment: Can this be tweaked to work with agg? So as to remove the need to index the columns?

Comment: Problem with `agg` is that it checks to see if the function actually reduces.  If it's an array and not a scalar, `agg` will yell at me (and I'm a sensitive snowflake).

Comment: Indeed. "function does not reduce" has been plaguing me all night.

Comment: @piRSquared - why use eval when you could `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).apply(lambda x: x[0], axis=1)`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Explored that possibility (see Scott's answer) It's really clunky.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - check my clunky answer with apply aswell :-)

Comment: In the end I don't believe there is a way around that clunkiness. I am severely disappointed by pandas because this should be something that is more easily attainable than it currently is. With that said I believe the series answer is the least hacky one.

Comment: Nice! That's a totally different route. Although I'll venture a guess and say your first answer would be faster.

Comment: All the same, I appreciate your efforts as well as the others. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ over the sample dataset, `defaultdict` answer is quicker.  `3.87 ms` vs. `5.74 ms`

Comment: Oh? That's pleasantly surprising. Although... For larger datasets, I believe the bottleneck will be iteritems in the list comp.... possibly. I should benchmark this.

Comment: OK, added a new faster answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['request','date'])[['count','users']].agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
             count users
request date            
2       1      1,1   1,3
        2        2     7
        3        3     3
3       2      3,1   1,7
        3      1,2   4,9
        4        1     7
        5        1     9
```

Comment: I guess you meant `lambda x: x.tolist()`? I would like the columns as a list.

Comment: I guess you could do `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).applymap(lambda x: x[0])
` but this is still pretty ugly.

Comment: what about `df.groupby(['date', 'request']).agg(lambda x: [x.tolist()]).apply(lambda x: x.str[0])`?

Comment: The fact that `df.agg` works means we are on the right track. But I'd ideally like that second apply call to disappear... somehow... hmm...

Answer (score 1):

Hacky way using `apply`, and could possible be very slow.

```
In [1274]: df.groupby(['date', 'request']).apply(
          lambda x: pd.Series({c: x[c].tolist() for c in ['count', 'users']}))
Out[1274]:
               count   users
date request
1    2        [1, 1]  [1, 3]
2    2           [2]     [7]
     3        [3, 1]  [1, 7]
3    2           [3]     [3]
     3        [1, 2]  [4, 9]
4    3           [1]     [7]
5    3           [1]     [9]
```