# grouping rows in a list of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID Description
1  A
1  B
1  C
2  A
2  C
3  A
```

I would like to group by the ID column and get the description as a list of list like this:

```
ID Description
1  [["A"],["B"],["C"]]
2  [["A"],["C"]]
3  [["A"]]
```

The `df.groupby('ID')['Description'].apply(list)` but this create only the "first level" of lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: @ViG I have seen this question and although it is similar to the one you mention, if you read more carefully, it is not the same as I want one extra level of listing.

Comment: sorry, my bad..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly different to @jezrael in that the listifying of strings is done via `map`. In addition call `reset_index()` adds "Description" explicitly to output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A'], [1, 'B'], [1, 'C'], [2, 'A'], [2, 'C'], [3, 'A']], columns=['ID', 'Description'])

df.groupby('ID')['Description'].apply(list).apply(lambda x: list(map(list, x))).reset_index()

# ID Description
# 1 [[A], [B], [C]] 
# 2 [[A], [C]] 
# 3 [[A]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need create inner `list`s:

```
print (df)
   ID Description
0   1         Aas
1   1           B
2   1           C
3   2           A
4   2           C
5   3           A

df = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: [x]).groupby(df['ID']).apply(list).reset_index()
```

Another solution similar like @jp_data_analysis with one `apply`:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['Description'].apply(lambda x: [[y] for y in x]).reset_index()
```

And pure python solution:

```
a = list(zip(df['ID'], df['Description']))
d = {}
for k, v in a:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append([v])
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(d.keys()), 'Description':list(d.values())}, 
                   columns=['ID','Description'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID        Description
0   1  [[Aas], [B], [C]]
1   2         [[A], [C]]
2   3              [[A]]
```