# Group rows in list and transpose pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

[grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby?noredirect=1&lq=1)

i have found question and need to go a step further

output required by this question was

```
A [1,2]
B [5,5,4]
C [6]
```

what I'am trying to achieve is

```
A B C
1 5 6
2 5 
  4
```

i have tried using

```
grouped=dataSet.groupby('Column1')
df = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

output im Stucked with is

```
df.T
Column1  A     B       C
        [1,2] [5,5,4] [6]
```

Comment: Why is literally every single pandas question today featuring columns of lists? They're terrible to work with, and not what pandas is meant for. Please re-evaluate your strategy.

Comment: hi there, I'm new to pandas and here I stuck badly scratching my head since this morning,  okay i'll make a note that pandas is not suitable for columns to list. can you suggest me any strategy to solve this problem? I've tried using pivot but didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think here there is no need to use columns of lists. 
You can achieve your result using a simple dictionary comprehension over the groups generated by groupby:

```
out = pd.concat({key: 
                    group['b'].reset_index(drop=True)
                for key, group in df.groupby('a')}, axis=1)
```

which gives the desired output:

```
out
Out[59]: 
     A  B    C
0  1.0  5  6.0
1  2.0  5  NaN
2  NaN  4  NaN
```

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: Glad to hear! don't forget to upvote/accept the question if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need create `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})

s = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).T
print (df)
a    A    B    C
0  1.0  5.0  6.0
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  NaN  4.0  NaN
```