# Convert groupby values into list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
label  data
a      1.09
b      2.1
a      5.0
b      2.0
c      1.9
```

What I want is

```
arr = [[1.09, 5.0], [2.1, 2.0],[1.9]]
```

preferably as a list of numpy arrays.

I know that `df.groupby.groups.keys()` gives me the list `['a','b','c']`, and `df.groupby.groups.values()` gives me something like `arr`, but as an `Int64Index` object. However, I tried `df.loc[df.groupby.groups.values()]['label']` and it isn't getting the desired result.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> preferably as a list of numpy arrays.

Preferably not, because you're asking for *ragged arrays*, which means that the inner arrays (AKA, the rows) are not all of the same length. This is inconvenient for numpy, meaning it cannot store these arrays efficiently as C arrays internally. It ends up falling back to slow python objects.

In this situation, I'd recommend nested python lists. That's achievable through a `groupby` + `apply`.

```
lst = df.groupby('label')['data'].apply(pd.Series.tolist).tolist()
print(lst)
[[1.09, 5.0], [2.1, 2.0], [1.9]]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error though: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: @irene ummm it's supposed to be the name of your column? Try again with a slightly different syntax please (edit made ^).

Comment: Ain't this the similar one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: @Dark yup. I'll keep this one here because of the little primer on arrays :)

Comment: Oh haha I see. Thanks! Also, is it guaranteed that this follows the order in `df.groupby('label').groups.keys()`? @coldspeed

Comment: @coldspeed Also, it's not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby...I want to get a list of lists, the other is looking for a dataframe. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @irene Hmm, that's a good question. I think the order is guaranteed when you do `df.groupby('label', sort=False).groups.keys()`.

Comment: @coldspeed Alternatively, can I try `df.groupby('label', sort=True)['data'].apply(pd.Series.tolist).tolist()`? Would that be a safer option?

Comment: @irene Safer? Depends on what you want? But with `sort=True` you are guaranteed the same order for the same keys.

Comment: @coldspeed I just want to make sure that I know which key corresponds to which array in the list. Thanks!