# Grouping values in a a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe like this

```
    Number  Names  
0   1       Josh   
1   2       Jon    
2   3       Adam   
3   4       Barsa  
4   5       Fekse  
5   6       Bravo  
6   7       Barsa 
7   8       Talyo  
8   9       Jon  
9   10      Zidane
```

how can i group these numbers based on names

```
for Number,Names in zip(dsa['Number'],dsa['Names'])
print(Number,Names)
```

The above code gives me following output

```
1 Josh
2 Jon
3 Adam
4 Barsa
5 Fekse
6 Bravo
7 Barsa
8 Talyo
9 Jon
10 Zidane
```

How can i get a output like below

```
1 Josh
2,9 Jon
3 Adam
4,7 Barsa
5 Fekse
6 Bravo
8 Talyo
10 Zidane
```

I want to group the numbers based on names

Comment: `df.groupby('Names').Number.apply(list)` should work, this is a duplicate question though. i'll find a better answer to link to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df.groupby("Names")["Number"].unique()
```

This will return you a series and then you can transform as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' `groupby` function with `agg` which aggregates columns. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Names']).agg({'Number' : ['unique']})
```

This is grouping by `Names` and within those groups reporting the unique values of `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the DF is:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'n':[1,2,3,4,5], 'name':['a','b','a','c','c']})

   n name
0  1    a
1  2    b
2  3    a
3  4    c
4  5    c
```

You can use groupby to group by name, and then apply 'list' to the n of those names:

```
A.groupby('name')['n'].apply(list)
name
a    [1, 3]
b       [2]
c    [4, 5]
```