# Combining similar rows within a dataframe column into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on the Chicago crimes dataset and I created a dataframe called primary which is just the type of crime. Then I grouped by the type of crime and got its count. This is the relevant code.

```py
primary = crimes2012[['Primary Type']].copy()
test=primary.groupby('PrimaryType').size().sort_values().reset_index(name='Count')
```

Now I have a dataframe 'test' which has the crimes and their count. What I want to do it merge together certain crimes. For example, "Non-Criminal" and "Non - Criminal" and "Non-Criminal(Subject Specified)". But because they're rows now I don't know how to do it. I was trying to use `.loc[]`

I also tried using

```py
test['Primary Type'=='NON-CRIMINAL'] = test['Primary Type'=='NON - CRIMINAL']+test['Primary Type'=='NON-CRIMINAL']+test['Primary Type'=='NON-CRIMINAL (SUBJECT SPECIFIED)']
```

but of course that only returned a Boolean value of false

Comment: Can you give a small sample date set and the expected outcome

Comment: The answer provided by Mortz is perfect, but given most datasets for analyses/datascience are huge, also consider the Numpy approach provided by B.M. in :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `map` or `apply` here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

You will have to create a mapping of your inputs to desired outputs as a dictionary
`desired_output = {"NON CRIMINAL": "NON-CRIMINAL", "NC": "NON-CRIMINAL", ...}`

and apply/map it to your `primary` series as follows -

`primary = primary.map(desired_output)`

And then `groupby` as you are doing now