# Applying filter functions on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of sales and purchases on a market place, looking a little like this.

```
User_ID | Transaction_Type |   Date   | Amount
    1   |      Sale        | 01/01/14 | 200.00
    2   |     Purchase     | 01/01/14 |  30.00
    ...
```

I need to filter out customers who have only bought or sold something versus customers who have bought and sold something at least once.

I am trying to create a function that will check if a user has done both or not. If a user has done both, then the user will be marked as a yes, otherwise no.

So far I have tried doing this,

```
def user_filter(df):
if df in df['User_ID'].filter(lambda x : ((x['Transaction_Type']=='Sale').any())&((x['Transaction_Type']=='Purchase').any())):
    return 'yes'
else:
    return 'no'
df['cross'] = df['User_ID'].apply(user_filter)
```

Let's assume later on in the dataset that User_ID 1 will come back as a Purchase. I would hope it would return as :

```
User_ID | Transaction_Type |   Date   | Amount | cross
    1   |      Sale        | 01/01/14 | 200.00 |  yes
    2   |     Purchase     | 01/01/14 |  30.00 |   no
```

but the following error returns:

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

When i apply it to the whole dataframe as opposed to just the series, it returns:

```
KeyError: ('User_ID', 'occurred at index User_ID')
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic for `cross`? IIUC, `cross`=`yes` requires BOTH `Sale` and `Purchase` for the **same** `User_ID`. Correct? Your expected output, you show `cross=yes` for **only** `Sale`. This confuses me.

Comment: You are applying to one series - User_Id try for the whole df

Comment: @KonradSitarz That returns `KeyError: ('User_ID', 'occurred at index User_ID')`

Comment: @edesz the following `df['User_ID'].filter(lambda x : ((x['Transaction_Type']=='Sale').any())&((x['Transaction_Type']=='Purchase').any()))` will filter only users who are both.

Comment: @KyleMcComb: `User_ID=1` does not have a `Sale`. Yet this user is assigned `cross=yes`. According to the verbal instructions you have posted, I would have thought they should be assigned `cross=no` and `cross=yes` should only be assigned if the **same** `User_ID` has `Sale` and `Purchase`. Please clarify

Comment: @edesz There are about 1000 + more observations in my dataframe and user 1 appears again as a sale. I just truncated it. apologies for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach to doing this is using `groupby` and then, instead of aggregating, simply list the `Transaction_Type`s in each group like show in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221675/4057186). Then, just get the length of the list....if the length is 2 this means both `Sale` and `Purchase` are present for that user. On the other hand, if the length is 1, then only one of `Sale` or `Purchase` is present for that user.

Generate some  data per the OP (I added a third record to make the output more explicit)

```
d = [['User_ID', 'Transaction_Type', 'Date', 'Amount'],
    [1, 'Sale', '01/01/14', 200],
    [1, 'Purchase','01/02/14',300],
    [2, 'Purchase','01/01/14',30],]
```

Perform the `GROUP BY`

```
df_users = df.groupby('User_ID')['Transaction_Type'].apply(list).reset_index(drop=False)
df_users.rename(columns={'Transaction_Type':'Transactions'}, inplace=True)

print(df_users)
   User_ID      Transactions
0        1  [Sale, Purchase]
1        2        [Purchase]
```

Now append a `cross` column to the grouped `DataFrame` and populate the `cross` column as required

```
df_users['cross'] = 'no'
df_users.loc[df_users.Transactions.apply(len)==2, 'cross'] = 'yes'

print(df_users)
   User_ID      Transactions cross
0        1  [Sale, Purchase]   yes
1        2        [Purchase]    no
```

**EDIT 1**

Alternatively, drop the `apply` steps and just use `size`

```
df_users = df.groupby('User_ID')['Transaction_Type'].size().reset_index(drop=False)
df_users['cross'] = 'no'
df_users.loc[df_users.Transactions==2, 'cross'] = 'yes'

print(df_users)
   User_ID  Transactions cross
0        1             2   yes
1        2             1    no
```

**EDIT 2**

If you wanted to append the `cross` column to the source `DataFrame`, then add these 2 lines of code to the above

```
df = df.merge(df_users, on='User_ID')
df.drop(columns=['Transactions'], inplace=True)

print(df)
   User_ID Transaction_Type      Date  Amount cross
0        1             Sale  01/01/14     200   yes
1        1         Purchase  01/02/14     300   yes
2        2         Purchase  01/01/14      30    no
```