# Categorize data into different bins

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of some products with their units and price. I want to work on price that falls in one category. For e.g

The data looks like this,

```
CATEGORY   UNIT    PRICE
Gloves     pair    50
Gloves     pack    100
Gloves     unit    80
Comb       set     150
Comb       pack    100
```

Considering the above data, the data can be categorized in two bins `Gloves` and `Comb`, which then further contains 3 and 2 bins respectively.
`Gloves - (pair, pack, unit)`, `Comb - (set, pack)`.

I did found some useful answers but that were only for 1-D data. How can I do so for such data ?

EDIT: The link [groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) was not quite helpful because it showed grouping for 2 columns, but I need grouping for 3 columns in my case (CATEGORIES->UNITS->PRICE).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `groupby` on `CATEGORY` and then `apply` a `list` operation to `UNIT`

```
df.groupby('CATEGORY')['UNIT'].apply(list).reset_index()

  CATEGORY                UNIT
0     Comb         [set, pack]
1   Gloves  [pair, pack, unit]

df.groupby('CATEGORY')['UNIT'].apply(list).reset_index().values

array([['Comb', list(['set', 'pack'])],
       ['Gloves', list(['pair', 'pack', 'unit'])]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: What could I do for the prices. Applying `groupby` on `unit` would consider all prices (irrespective of category) and that would be wrong.