# Converting CSV to Dictionary with one column as keys and one column as its values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Hello I have a CSV file of the format below:

```
ticket asset
1111   3456
1111   6789
1122   2345
1122   7890
```

I want to convert it to a Dict like:

```
{'1111': ['3456', '6789'], '1122':['2345', '7890']}
```

Basically want to have the ticket as 'key' and all the assets under that ticket as 'values'.

the csv.DictReader() helped a little but I am unable to extract unique ticket number for keys and match all the asset under it for values.

Any help would be great :)

Thanks for getting the CSV > Dict so quick!

If I want to convert a Tuple to Dict, how will that work?

e.g: Tuple:
((1111, 3456), (1111, 6789), (1122, 2345), (1122, 7890))

and I want that to be converted to:

{'1111': ['3456', '6789'], '1122':['2345', '7890']}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader) # toss headers
    for ticket, asset in reader:
        d[ticket].append(asset)
```

With regular dictionary:

```
import csv

d = {}
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader) # toss headers
    for ticket, asset in reader:
        d.setdefault(ticket, []).append(asset)
```

Comment: `for ticket, asset in reader: d.setdefault(ticket, []).append(asset)` is also a possibility.

Comment: @TimPietzcker:  Fair enough.  Creating and destroying a throwaway list is no worse than the extra in-statement. Plus it's shorter.  Updating answer.

Comment: worked like a charm - only thing I had to change was  to set delimiter = ","

Answer (score 0):

Import your csv into a pandas dataframe. Use applymap to convert the dataframe into string data type. Group by ticket and convert all collected asset as a list. Then convert the dataframe into a dictionary(dict)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0)
df=df.applymap(str).groupby('ticket')['asset'].apply(list).to_dict()
print(df)
```

Result:

```
{'1111': ['3456', '6789'], '1122': ['2345', '7890']}
```