# Pandas group a column by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
A B
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d
2 e
2 f
```

I want to get a list of values for column 'B' by column 'A', so the final product would look like:

```
list_one = [a, b, c]
list_two = [d, e, f]
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['A','B'])
```

But, this doesn't do what I want it to do.

What would be an elegant pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to group by `A` only: `df.groupby(['A'])`

Comment: `[[*v] for _, v in df.groupby('A')['B']]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'A':1, 'B': 'a'},
    {'A':1, 'B': 'b'},
    {'A':1, 'B': 'c'},
    {'A':2, 'B': 'd'},
    {'A':2, 'B': 'e'},
    {'A':2, 'B': 'f'}])

list(df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).values)

# Output
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[x['B'].values.tolist() for _,x in df.groupby('A')]
```

Output

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```