# How to create a pivot table in R or Python similar to one i have created in Excel?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have data in below format:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>T_id</th><th>Task_name</th><th>product_id</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A1</td><td>10120</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A2</td><td>10122</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>B1</td><td>10111</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>B1</td><td>10120</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>A1</td><td>10122</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I'm able to convert the above format manually using excel in below format

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Task_id</th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>10120</td><td>10122 </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>10111</td><td>10120</td><td>10122</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Can somebody please help me with Python or R program. I have used pivot(), pivot_table() in python & cast, reshape in R. But i couldn't get the required output.

Comment: "I have used pivot(), pivot_table() in python & cast, reshape in R. But i couldn't get the required output." - if you have used these, can you show us what you've tried and where you are getting errors?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for in `R`?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(T_id) %>% summarise(product_id = paste(product_id, collapse =  " ") )

#   T_id product_id                    
#1     1 10120 10122       
#2     2 10111 10120 10122
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and the `.apply(list)`.

## Solution

#### Make Data

```py
html = """<table><tbody><tr><th>T_id</th><th>Task_name</th><th>product_id</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A1</td><td>10120</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A2</td><td>10122</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>B1</td><td>10111</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>B1</td><td>10120</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>A1</td><td>10122</td></tr></tbody></table>"""
```

#### Make Dataframe and Apply `groupby`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
df.groupby('T_id')['product_id'].apply(list)
```

**Output**:

```
T_id
1           [10120, 10122]
2    [10111, 10120, 10122]
Name: product_id, dtype: object
```

If you want to change the index,

```py
df.groupby('T_id')['product_id'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Product_IDs')
```

**Output**:

```
T_id    Product_IDs
0   1   [10120, 10122]
1   2   [10111, 10120, 10122]
```

### Optional Stuff

If you are loading an html either directly from a website or as a string, please refer to [this article](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/parsing-html-tables-in-python-with-pandas/).

### References

1. [Loading html into a dataframe](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/parsing-html-tables-in-python-with-pandas/)
2. [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)