# Python Pandas dataframe cross-referencing and new column generation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to generate a dataframe that contains lists of a person's potential favorite crayon colors, based on their favorite color. I have two dataframes that contain the necessary information:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person':['Jeff','Marie','Jenna','Mike'], 'color':['blue', 'purple', 'brown', 'green']}, columns=['person','color'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'possible_crayons':['christmas red','infra red','scarlet','sunset orange', 'neon carrot','lemon','forest green','pine','navy','aqua','periwinkle','royal purple'],'color':['red','red','red','orange','orange','yellow','green','green','blue','blue','purple','purple']}, columns=['possible_crayons','color'])
```

I want to reference one database against the other by matching the df1 color entry to the df2 color entry, and returning the corresponding possible_crayons values as a list in a new column in df1. Any terms that did not find a match would be labeled N/A. So the desired output would be:

```
person favorite_color possible_crayons_list  
Jeff   blue           [navy, aqua]  
Marie  purple         [periwinkle, royal purple]  
Jenna  brown          NaN  
Mike   green          [forest green, pink]
```

I've tried:

```
mergedDF = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

However, this results in the following:

```
  person   color possible_crayons  
0   Jeff    blue             navy  
1   Jeff    blue             aqua  
2  Marie  purple       periwinkle  
3  Marie  purple     royal purple  
4  Jenna   brown              NaN  
5   Mike   green     forest green  
6   Mike   green             pine
```

Is there any way to achieve my desired output of lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person':['Jeff','Marie','Jenna','Mike'], 'color':['blue', 'purple', 'brown', 'green']}, columns=['person','color'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'possible_crayons':['christmas red','infra red','scarlet','sunset orange', 'neon carrot','lemon','forest green','pine','navy','aqua','periwinkle','royal purple'],'color':['red','red','red','orange','orange','yellow','green','green','blue','blue','purple','purple']}, columns=['possible_crayons','color'])

tmp = df2.groupby('color')['possible_crayons'].apply(list)
mergedDF = df1.merge(tmp, how='left', left_on='color', right_index=True)

print(mergedDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how='left'` and then [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with **`as_index=False`**:

```
new_df= ( df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='color')
             .groupby(['color','person'],as_index=False).agg(list) )
```

**Output**

```
print(new_df)
    color person            possible_crayons
0    blue   Jeff                [navy, aqua]
1   brown  Jenna                       [nan]
2   green   Mike        [forest green, pine]
3  purple  Marie  [periwinkle, royal purple]
```

Answer (score 0):

`mergedDF2 = mergedDF.groupby('color')['possible_crayons'].apply(list).reset_index(name='new_possible_crayons')`

Comment: Can you provide some detail on why this solution works?