# python dataframe - grouping rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python so the question might not be so clear.

I have this dataset with pandas dataframe that goes something like this.

```
        Id       item
0      A0029V93  B0239WN
1      A0029V93  B0302SS
2      A02948s8  B0029ST
...
```

and the result I want is

```
        Id       item
0      A0029V93  (B0239WN,B0302SS)
1      A02948s8  (B0029ST, ...)
2      ...       ...
...
```

No duplicate Id and all the items in the data paired with the ID
It doesn't necessarily have to look like this
as long as I can get the `Id,[item]` data.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Id')['item'].apply(list)
```

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: thx for the help!
Didn't know there was a same question couldn't find it.