# create a 'group number' column for a pandas data frame column of '0' and '1' s

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get the data frame below

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'val':[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
             'groups':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,'ignore','ignore']})

     val    groups
0     0       1
1     0       1
2     1       1
3     1       1
4     1       1
5     0       2
6     0       2
7     0       2
8     0       2
9     1       2
10    1       2
11    0       3
12    1       3
13    1       3
14    1       3
15    1       3
16    0  ignore
17    0  ignore
```

I have a series `df.val` with has values `[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]`.
**How to create *`df.groups`* from *`df.val`*.**

first `0,0,1,1,1` will form group `1`,(*i.e. from the beginning upto next occurrence of `0` after  `1`'s*)
`0,0,0,0,1,1` will form group `2`, (incremental group number, starting where previous group ended uptill next occurrence of `0` after  `1`'s),...etc

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Duplicate. Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: Why is last group `ignore` ?

Comment: @jezrael does not have `1`'s following zeroes, so have to avoid that group while doing `groupby` later

Comment: big thanks guys `@jezrael` and `@YO and BEN_W`, couldn't find any solution after trying for more tan 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First test if next value after `0` is `1` and create groups by sumulative sums by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = (dd['val'].eq(0) & dd['val'].shift().eq(1)).cumsum().add(1)
```

Then convert last group to `ignore` if last value of data are `0` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = s.eq(s.max()) & (dd['val'].iat[-1] == 0)
dd['new'] = np.where(mask, 'ignore', s)
print (dd)
    val  groups     new
0     0       1       1
1     0       1       1
2     1       1       1
3     1       1       1
4     1       1       1
5     0       2       2
6     0       2       2
7     0       2       2
8     0       2       2
9     1       2       2
10    1       2       2
11    0       3       3
12    1       3       3
13    1       3       3
14    1       3       3
15    1       3       3
16    0  ignore  ignore
17    0  ignore  ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC first we do `diff` and `cumsum` , then we need to find the condition to ignore the previous value we get (`np.where`)

```
s=df.val.diff().eq(-1).cumsum()+1
df['New']=np.where(df['val'].eq(1).groupby(s).transform('any'),s,'ignore')
df
    val  groups     New
0     0       1       1
1     0       1       1
2     1       1       1
3     1       1       1
4     1       1       1
5     0       2       2
6     0       2       2
7     0       2       2
8     0       2       2
9     1       2       2
10    1       2       2
11    0       3       3
12    1       3       3
13    1       3       3
14    1       3       3
15    1       3       3
16    0  ignore  ignore
17    0  ignore  ignore
```