# Find all row entries with the same entry in another column using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Currently I have a very large csv that roughly has a structure like the below.

```
Id   label   attribute     link
1  usernamea   500    https://someurl.com
2  usernameb   422    https://someurl.com
3  usernamec   4422   https://anotherurl.com
```

I'm trying to find a way using Python and pandas to selecting all the instances where two people have shared the same link and then writing that into a new csv by their Id. Worth mentioning I created the Id column as an index when using `df.to_csv` to create this csv.

So for example going off the instance above the output I need would be:

```
source  target 
   1      2
```

Since `usernamea` and `usernameb` both shared https://someurl.com.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: does it always comes in pair? is there a chance there are more than two users with the same link?

Comment: There are often more than two users with the same link and I need all those instances. I should say it doesn't matter what order the 1,2 are in the next csv - i.e. it isn't a problem if the output is 2,1.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: Yes it did thank you! df.groupby('link)['label'].unique() solved this for me