# How do I convert a pandas column to a series of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two-column pandas dataframe, and would like to convert the data as follows. Please advise, and thank you!

```
df in:
column1   column2
a         g
a         h
b         t
b         r
b         i
b         k
b         ft
c         w
c         mm
c         n
c         qq

df out:
column1   column2
a         g, h
b         t, r, i, k, ft
c         w, mm, n, qq
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/q/22219004/4611565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't solved it yet:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['column1'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
print(df)

  column1         column2
0       a            g, h
1       b  t, r, i, k, ft
2       c    w, mm, n, qq
```