# GroupBy DataFrame to column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with two columns - `id` and `image`. But `ids` are duplicated since one product (id) can have multiple images.

I'm trying to convert this DataFrame into a DataFrame with unique `id` column and `image` column which has lists of image URLs as values.

```
      id  image
0     10  https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1
1     10  https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2
2     10  https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3
3     20  https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/4
4     20  https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/5
```

I want to convert DF above to this format:

```
      id  image
0     10  ['https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/1','https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2','https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3']
1     20  ['https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/4','https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/5',]
```

I could use some a loop but maybe there is a more simple/efficient way to do this since `DataFrame` has a `GroupBy` option.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).image.apply(list)`.