# How to count in dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains data about buyers and sellers. I wanted to groupby each pair to see how many times a seller and buyer have a transaction, this also sums all their transaction to work out the total spent in their transactions:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID of seller','ID of buyer', 'currency'])["Total spent"].sum().reset_index(drop = False)
```

this gives me:

df2 =

```
ID of seller    ID of buyer    Currency   Total spent
871             356            GBP        60
473             784            GBP        40
etc...
```

I want to add another column which states how many times each pair has traded. So it would look like:

```
ID of seller    ID of buyer    Currency   Total spent  Num of transactions
871             356            GBP        60           2
etc...
```

from my understanding this would be done using .count() but i can't seem to work out where to fit it in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You should provide a a reproducible example and the desired result for testing

```
df.groupby(['ID of seller','ID of buyer', 'currency']).agg(total_spent=('Total spent', 'sum'), num_txn=('Total spent', 'count'))
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation for the documentation.