# how do i group the values of csv file using panda based on values of row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which has data in this format. Here i want to group by elements using 2 column values.

```
col1  col2  col3
abc   001    mango
abc   001    apple
abc   001    orange
abc   002    potato
xyz   003    cabbage
xyz   003    peas
xyz   004    ladyfinger
```

I want the output in this format

```
col1  col2  col3
abc   001   [mango,apple,orange]
abc   002   [potato]
xyz   003   [cabbage,peas]
xyz   004   [ladyfinger]
```

I want to group the values of col3 on basis of clo2 values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])["col3"].apply(list).reset_index() , although groups by both col1 and col2 so only work in provided example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3': lambda col: list(col)}).reset_index()
```

or

```
df.groupby('col2').agg(col1=pandas.NamedAgg(column='col1', aggfunc='first'), col3=pandas.NamedAgg(column='col3', aggfunc=lambda col: list(col))).reset_index()
```

Comment: This will not yield what OP needs.

Comment: it worked for col2 and col3 values are showing but col1 is not showing

Comment: Try this for column 1 to be present :`df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3': lambda col: list(col)}).reset_index()`

Comment: sorry my mistake. In other way: df.groupby('col2').agg(c1=pd.NamedAgg(column='col1', aggfunc='first', c3=pd.NamedAgg(column='col3', aggfunc=lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()

Comment: Its working. I want to know if i am providing column name as 'Column 1' it gives keyword error. why?

Comment: because if dataframe there is no columns 'Column 1'

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3': lambda col: list(col)}).reset_index()
```

You can achieve it with the code above