# Python DataFrame: Map two columns based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df with three columns `no` , `name`, `date` .  If `no` and `date` are matched thier value will be added in `output` column to a list.

Ex: 1234 and 2 matched from 0 and 1 rows - so [a,b]

If `no` and `date` doesn't match add the same `name` value to list

```
      no       name   date

0   1234        a       2

1   1234        b       2

2   1234        c       3

3   456         d       1

4   456         e       2  

5   789         f       5
```

Resultant Output.

```
      no       name   date    output

0   1234        a       2     [a,b]

1   1234        b       2     [a,b]

2   1234        c       3      [c]

3   456         d       1      [d]

4   456         e       2      [e]

5   789         f       5      [f]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to combine `groupby` and `transform` with `sum` and `list`. You'd have to see about the performance though.

```
df['output'] = df.groupby(['no', 'date'])['name'].transform(sum).apply(list)

     no name date  output
0  1234    a    2  [a, b]
1  1234    b    2  [a, b]
2  1234    c    3     [c]
3   456    d    1     [d]
4   456    e    2     [e]
5   789    f    5     [f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby.agg(list)` to get the list for each combination of `no` and `date`, then `merge` to assign  back:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['no','date'])['name']
           .agg(list).rename('output'),
         on=['no', 'date']
        )
```

Output:

```
     no name  date  output
0  1234    a     2  [a, b]
1  1234    b     2  [a, b]
2  1234    c     3     [c]
3   456    d     1     [d]
4   456    e     2     [e]
5   789    f     5     [f]
```