# How to group Pandas rows and present the output as dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, dictionary, conditional-statements

I would like to get for each category/eye colour to have all the associated first names.

Here is my dataframe (df):

```
      eye color           first name 
0     blue                Jules
1     blue                Lucie
2     green               Thomas
3     green               Vincent
4     green               David
5     brown               Maxime
```

This is the output I would like to have:

```
{'blue': ['Jules', 'Lucie'], 'green': ['Thomas', 'Vincent', 'David'], 'brown': ['Maxime']
```

This is my code:

```
list_name=list()

for i in range(len(df)-1):
    
    current_color=df['eye color'][i]
    
    next_color=df['eye color'][i+1] 
    
    name=df['first name'][i]
    
    if current_color!=next_color : 

        compte_nb_systeme=compte_nb_systeme+1        
        print('we change eye color')
    else :
        print('we don't change the color of the eye')
        list_name.append(name)
        
   dico= {current_color :list_name}            
print(dico)
```

the problem is that I add all the names contained in the column 'first name' and that for each color of eyes.

Comment: ``df.groupby('eye color')['first name'].apply(list).to_dict()`` ?

Comment: It's working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This code iterates over all rows of `df` and adds the `first name` to the dict entry of the `eye color`. For the first occurrence of a color (`color not in output`) the entry in the dict must be created, it is initialized to an empty list (`output[color] = []`).

```py
output = {}

for i in range(len(df)):

    color = df['eye color'][i]
    first_name = df['first name'][i]

    if color not in output:
        output[color] = []
    output[color].append(first_name)
    
print(output)
```

Comment: I understand my mistake better. Thank you.