# How to organize values in one list by common values in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, one with IDs and one with values corresponding to that list. Sometimes the first list can have multiple of the same IDs. For example:

```
list_of_IDs    = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, ..., 100, 100,100]
list_of_values = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, ...,   8,   9, 10]
```

I want to combine these lists into a dictionary (or similar) such that I have the list of values for each ID:

```
dict_of_vals_for_IDs = {0: [0,1,2], 1:[0,1,2,3], 2:[0], 3:[1,2], ...,100:[8,9,10]}
```

What is the quickest and most efficient way to do this?

Edit: I have tried a number of solutions that loop over each unique value in list_of_IDs and find all indices corresponding to each ID. However, these solutions seem to be quite slow since my actual lists are millions of elements long. Is there a quicker solution than one that uses loops or list comprehensions?

Comment: What have you tried and what are getting stuck on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize a dict, then iterate through each of the IDs and values and then update the dict with those values.

```
dict_of_vals_for_IDs = {i: [] for i in set(list_of_IDs)}
for k, v in zip(list_of_IDs, list_of_values):
    dict_of_vals_for_IDs[k].append(v)
```

Comment: This ended up being the fastest solution of the three current options:
balderman: 5.25s.
CypherX: 125.15s.
Kevin Sheng: 4.77s

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Apart from what others have suggested as answers, you could also do this using `pandas` library. This may not be optimal if you have very little need for using `pandas`. But given the many scenarios where one could use `pandas`, here is an option.

> The **benchmarking** section below shows that *a typical list length of `1e8` (i.e **100 Million**), the wall time for execution is about **`23 seconds`**. For **one million** records the execution time is around `350 ms`*.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list_of_IDs, 'VALUE': list_of_values})
df.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].apply(list).to_dict()

## Output: 
# {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0], 3: [1, 2], 100: [8, 9, 10]}
```

### Single line solution

You could equivalently write all the operations as a chain of operations and get what you want in a single line (broken into multiple lines for enhanced readability) as follows.

```py
pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': list_of_IDs, 
    'VALUE': list_of_values
}).groupby('ID')['VALUE'].apply(list).to_dict()

## Output: 
# {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0], 3: [1, 2], 100: [8, 9, 10]}
```

### Dummy Data

```py
list_of_IDs    = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 100, 100, 100]
list_of_values = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10]
```

### Benchmarking Speed of Execution

Let us first prepare some dummy data (`N = 1e4, 1e5, 1e6, 1e7, 1e8`) and then use this data to benchmark the execution (wall) time. It shows that a typical list length of `1e8` (i.e **100 Million**), the wall time for execution is about 23 seconds. For **one million** records the execution time is around `350 ms`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 1e8
N = int(N)
ids = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=N)
values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=N)
```

I used a Google Colab notebook and rand the following in a cell with the data prepared in above.

```py
# run in a notebook
%%time 
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ids, 
    'VALUE': values
}).groupby('ID')['VALUE'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

**Output**:

```sh
|  N  | CPU Times (user, sys, total) | Wall Time |
|-----|------------------------------|-----------|
| 1e8 | (18.5  s, 4.38  s, 22.9  s)  | 23  s     |
| 1e7 | (2.19  s, 212  ms, 2.4   s)  | 2.4  s    |
| 1e6 | (317  ms, 31.6 ms, 348  ms)  | 352 ms    |
| 1e5 | (28.5 ms, 10.9 ms, 39.4 ms)  | 42  ms    |
| 1e4 | (12.6 ms, 2.92 ms, 15.5 ms)  | 18  ms    |
```

### Refrences

- [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: @jruss Did you see the benchmarking section? I think you mentioned `speed` is concern for millions of rows of data. I compared `1`, `10` and `100` **million** rows of data.

Comment: I like the use of pandas, especially in the one-line solution but it actually ended up being significantly slower than the other solutions. See the accepted solution for my benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
from collections import defaultdict
ids    = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
values = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
d = defaultdict(list)
for idx,x in enumerate(ids):
  d[x].append(values[idx])
print(d)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0], 3: [1, 2]})
```