# How to aggregate, combining dataframes, with pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` and a column `df['table']` such that each item in `df['table']` is another dataframe with the same headers/number of columns. I was wondering if there's a way to do a `groupby` like this:

Original dataframe:

```
name    table
Bob     Pandas df1
Joe     Pandas df2
Bob     Pandas df3
Bob     Pandas df4
Emily   Pandas df5
```

After groupby:

```
name    table
Bob     Pandas df containing the appended df1, df3, and df4
Joe     Pandas df2
Emily   Pandas df5
```

I found this code snippet to do a `groupby` and lambda for strings in a dataframe, but haven't been able to figure out how to append entire dataframes in a `groupby`.

```py
df['table'] = df.groupby(['name'])['table'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
```

I've also tried `df['table'] = df.groupby(['name'])['HTML'].apply(list)`, but that gives me a `df['table']` of all `NaN`.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given 3 dataframes

```py
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['pie', 'steak', 'milk']})
```

- Given another dataframe, with dataframes in the columns

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Emily'], 'table': [dfa, dfa, dfb, dfc, dfb]})

# print the type for the first value in the table column, to confirm it's a dataframe
print(type(df.loc[0, 'table']))
[out]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

- Each group of dataframes, can be combined into a single dataframe, by using `.groupby` and aggregating a `list` for each group, and combining the dataframes in the `list`, with `pd.concat`

```py
# if there is only one column, or if there are multiple columns of dataframes to aggregate
dfg = df.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: pd.concat(list(x)).reset_index(drop=True))

# display(dfg.loc['Bob', 'table'])
       a
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      a
4      b
5      c
6    pie
7  steak
8   milk

# to specify a single column, or specify multiple columns, from many columns
dfg = df.groupby('name')[['table']].agg(lambda x: pd.concat(list(x)).reset_index(drop=True))
```

### Not a duplicate

- Originally, I had marked this question as a duplicate of [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004), thinking the dataframes could be aggregated into a `list`, and then combined with `pd.concat`.

```py
df.groupby('name')['table'].apply(list)
df.groupby('name').agg(list)
df.groupby('name')['table'].agg(list)
df.groupby('name').agg({'table': list})
df.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

- However, these all result in a `StopIteration` error, when there are `dataframes` to aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Here let's create a dataframe with dataframes as columns:

First, I start with three dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

#creating dataframes that we will assign to Bob and Joe, notice b's and j':

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[12, 34, -4, None], 'letter':['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[1, 23, 44, 0], 'letter':['j1', 'j2', 'j3', 'j4']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[22, -3, 7, 78], 'letter':['b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8']})

#lets make a list of dictionaries:
list_of_dfs = [
    {'name':'Bob' ,'table':df1},
    {'name':'Joe' ,'table':df2},
    {'name':'Bob' ,'table':df3}
]

#constuct the main dataframe:
original_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dfs)
print(original_df)

original_df.shape #shows (3, 2)
```

Now we have the original dataframe created as the input, we will produce the resulting new dataframe. In doing so, we use groupby(),agg(), and pd.concat(). We also reset the index.

```
new_df = original_df.groupby('name')['table'].agg(lambda series: pd.concat(series.tolist())).reset_index()
print(new_df)

#check that Bob's table is now a concatenated table of df1 and df3:
new_df[new_df['name']=='Bob']['table'][0]
```

The output to the last line of code is:

```
    var1    letter
0   12.0    b1
1   34.0    b2
2   -4.0    b3
3    NaN    b4
0   22.0    b5
1   -3.0    b6
2    7.0    b7
3   78.0    b8
```

Comment: You can also get the final output with this codeline: `new_df.set_index('name').loc['Bob','table']`