# How do I create a list of values in a column from several values from another column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with these values:

```
filename, keyword, page
A, red, 1
A, red, 2
A, green, 1
B, red, 1
B, green, 1
C, green, 2
```

How can I transform this to the following format?

```
filename, keywords, pages
A, [red, green], [1,2]
B, [red, green], [1]
C, [green], [2]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Pandas? If a list isn't allowed as a cell value, is there another datatype that I could use that Pandas would allow? Or an alternative to a Pandas dataframe that I could store this in and then save it to a csv?

Comment: `groupby(filename).agg(set)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

you could use df.groupby(["filename"])['keyword','page'].agg(set)

```
keyword page
filename        
A   {green, red}    {1, 2}
B   {green, red}    {1}
C   {green} {2}
```

(
PS: updated based on  Ch3steR answers, i was only using list instead of set