# How to group dataframe rows into series in pandas groupby

Tags: pandas

I am trying to group by data into series. A similar question can be found on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby) but it groupby data into a list and I want into series. Any idea.

For list, the solution is like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6],'c':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})

df1.groupby('a').agg(list)
```

I tried something like this

```
df1.groupby(a).agg(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
```

But its not working
So I tried this

```
for i in df1.columns:
  df1[i]=df1[i].apply(lambda x:np.array(x))
```

But I want to convert to sereis

I want output like this

```
      b      c 
A   1 2     1 2
B   5 5 4   5 5 4
C   6       6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1.astype(str).groupby('a')['b'].agg(','.join).to_frame()
```

Output:

```
       b
a       
A    1,2
B  5,5,4
C      6
```

Comment: if i have more than 1 column, I got this error.
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'`

Comment: Remove the to_ framr with more than one column you don't need it.

Comment: but it will be str type instead of series type

Comment: You want a list or comma separated string?

Comment: i want pandas series