# concatenating values from rows depending if values are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

```
service   |  company
--------------------
sequencing|  Fischer
RNA tests |  Fischer
Cell tests|  23andMe
consulting|  UCLA
DNA tests |  UCLA
mouse test|  UCLA
```

and I want to `concat` services together into a list on equal company names like this:

```
service_list                           |  company
-------------------------------------------------
['sequencing','RNA tests']             |  Fischer
['Cell tests']                         |  23andMe
['consulting','DNA tests','mouse test']|  UCLA
```

Not sure how to begin doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 2):

Lets try groupby(), aggregate to list

```
df.groupby('company').service.agg(list).reset_index()




company                            service
0  23andMe                        [Celltests]
1  Fischer             [sequencing, RNAtests]
2     UCLA  [consulting, DNAtests, mousetest]
```