# Create dictionary from dataframe without a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is an example of my dataframe and a dictionary of what I'm looking to compute from it. My current method involves looping through unique ColA values, create a subset dataframe, getting list of ColB values, and make a dict from that. Problem is I have over a million unique ColA values to loop through. Any ideas??

DF

```
 ColA       ColB
 mike        34
 mike         3
 mike        10
 bill        80
 dean         2
 dean         4
 dean        44
 dean        56
```

desired dictionary = `{'mike':[34,3,10], 'bill': [10], 'dean': [2,4,44,56]}`

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: I'm assuming the value of `'bill'` key should be `[80]` not `[10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
out = df.groupby("ColA")["ColB"].agg(list).to_dict()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'bill': [80], 'dean': [2, 4, 44, 56], 'mike': [34, 3, 10]}
```