# python panda groupby and eliminate duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to go to as few stores as possible to get my products. How do I do this?
I have a list of stores that carry a specific product.

```
wanted_Products = pd.DataFrame({'p':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
stores = pd.DataFrame({'Store': np.repeat(np.arange(1,5),4),
                       'Product': [1,2,3,5,0,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,0,1,2,6]})
# return 1 if the Product is wanted
stores['Wanted'] = stores.Product.isin(wanted_Products.p).values.astype(int)

     Store  Product  Wanted
0       1        1       1
1       1        2       1
2       1        3       1
3       1        5       1
4       2        0       0
5       2        2       1
6       2        3       1
7       2        4       1
8       3        0       0
9       3        6       1
10      3        7       1
11      3        8       0
12      4        0       0
13      4        1       1
14      4        2       1
15      4        6       1

# Group products per store and calculate how many wanted products are in a store
w = stores.groupby('Store', as_index=False).agg(list)
w['Number_wanted'] = stores.groupby('Store', as_index=False)['Wanted'].sum().agg(list)['Wanted']

      Store  Product        Wanted         Number_wanted  ?Products_wanted?
0      1  [1, 2, 3, 5]  [1, 1, 1, 1]              4            [1,2,3,5]
1      2  [0, 2, 3, 4]  [0, 1, 1, 1]              3            [2,3,4]
2      3  [0, 6, 7, 8]  [0, 1, 1, 0]              2            [6,7]
3      4  [0, 1, 2, 6]  [0, 1, 1, 1]              3            [1,2,6]
```

How do I get the Products I want in a new column (Products_wanted) without the non wanted products? when I use isin() I only get true/false (1/0 if I use astype(int)) not  the actual numbers.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve]

Comment: A good place to start: [Pandas groupby list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby/)

Comment: I treid something that i did with whitelisting stores = (stores.assign(key=lambda x: x["Store"].sub(0))
          .merge(wanted_products left_on="key", right_index=True, how="left").drop("key", axis="columns")). First I make wanted_products to a panda

Comment: @Johanna Marklund you should definitely include your above comment in the question itself. That will show people that you have made a good faith effort to solve the problem, and can also help other people build upon what you have tried to get you an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this could be to keep track of all products that are availabe in a store, get them and then mark those products as **"taken"** so that you do not pick the same in next stores.

So initially you have **`wanted_Products`**`= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`**.** Since you are getting `[1, 2, 3, 5]` from **store 1**, you select and return these as products to get from **store 1**, and then mark all these as **"taken"** simply by replacing these values in `wanted_Products` to something else like say **`-1`** *(or some other value you like, to denote they have been taken)*.

Now  **`wanted_Products`**`= [-1,-1,-1,4,-1,6,7]`. `-1` ones are taken so you only have `[4,6,7]` products to get from next stores. Repeating the same logic for all stores will give you the products to get from there, without any duplicates:

```
def get_products(possible, wanted):
    i = np.where(np.in1d(wanted, possible))
    available = wanted[i]
    wanted[i] = -1
    return available

w = stores.groupby('Store', as_index=False).agg(list)
w['Products to get'] = w.Product.apply(get_products, args=(np.array(wanted_Products),))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> w
   Store       Product Products to get
0      1  [1, 2, 3, 5]    [1, 2, 3, 5]
1      2  [0, 2, 3, 4]             [4]
2      3  [0, 6, 7, 8]          [6, 7]
3      4  [0, 1, 2, 6]              []
```

Comment: It almost works, but if most products are in store 3 or 4 it will not work.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you give an example where it won't work?

Comment: if you switch products from store 1 and 3, then the product 2,3 will be taken in store 2 even if more products are gathered from store 3( after switch)  I have used your as_index for getting a nice dataFrame. thank you, this was also a problem that I ran into.

Answer (score 1):

To respect your optimization criteria (*always buy from the store that has the
greatest number of products from your list*), the list of products per store
needs to sorted **again** on **every iteration**: every time you decide that you're
getting a set of products from a given store, the remaining lists need to be
cleaned up (remove already-bought products) and re-ordered by length.

As a technical note, I'm converting your lists to sets, because you don't want
duplicates, so it's ok to do it, and it gives us set operations : intersection
(to check which wanted products are available in a given store) and difference
(remove already boughtproducts from the wanted list.)

The code is not too elegant, but I included quite a few comments:

```
stores = pd.DataFrame({'Store': np.repeat(np.arange(1,5),4),
                   'Product': [1,2,3,5,0,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,0,1,2,6]})
# stores = pd.DataFrame({'Store': np.repeat(np.arange(1,5),4),
#                    'Product': [0,2,7,6,0,2,4,8,1,2,7,6,1,2,3,5]})

w = stores.groupby('Store', as_index=False).agg(list)
w['Products to get'] = np.nan
w['Products to get'] = w['Products to get'].astype('object')

wanted_Products = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
wanted = set(wanted_Products)

tmp = w[['Store', 'Product']]
while len(wanted) > 0:
    # Removed unwanted products (set intersection)
    tmp['Product'] = tmp.Product.apply(lambda x: set(x) & wanted)
    
    # Sort on length of product sets
    tmp['lengths'] = tmp.Product.str.len()
    tmp = tmp.sort_values(by='lengths', ascending=False).drop('lengths', 1)

    # Get products from this store, remove them from wanted set
    get = tmp.loc[tmp.index[0], 'Product'] & wanted
    wanted -= get

    # Update Products to get for this store
    row = w[w['Store'] == tmp.loc[tmp.index[0], 'Store']]
    w.at[row.index[0], 'Products to get'] = get

    # Remove the largest product set, work on the remaining ones
    tmp = tmp.iloc[1:, ]
```

Here's the output:

```
In [71]: w
Out[71]: 
   Store       Product Products to get
0      1  [1, 2, 3, 5]    {1, 2, 3, 5}
1      2  [0, 2, 3, 4]             {4}
2      3  [0, 6, 7, 8]          {6, 7}
3      4  [0, 1, 2, 6]             NaN
```

With more products in stores 3 and 4, it still works:

```
stores = pd.DataFrame({'Store': np.repeat(np.arange(1,5),4),
                   'Product': [0,2,7,6,0,2,4,8,1,2,7,6,1,2,3,5]})
```

Output is:

```
In [76]: w
Out[76]: 
   Store       Product Products to get
0      1  [0, 2, 7, 6]             NaN
1      2  [0, 2, 4, 8]             {4}
2      3  [1, 2, 7, 6]    {1, 2, 6, 7}
3      4  [1, 2, 3, 5]          {3, 5}
```