# Aliasing aggregated column with reset_index()

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["a", 1],
        ["a", 11],
        ["c", 12],
        ["c", 15]
    ],
    columns=["col1","col2"]
)

grouped = df.groupby(["col1"])["col2"].sum().reset_index(name="ccc")
print(grouped)
```

(As example, taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221675/1609729))

This is bit unclear for me, how resetting index is related to aliasing/naming new aggregated column, but even more I don't get why this not raises: `reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'` error, because as [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) says there is no "name" argument for `reset_index()`.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is ouput of aggregation one column (specified after `groupby`) is `Series`, so is called [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `name` parameter:

> name, optional

> The name to use for the column containing the original Series values. Uses self.name by default. This argument is ignored when drop is True.

not [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) without `name` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, "Reason is ouput of aggregation one column is Series", it sems not all aggregate function returning series? I mean `count` for example, throws error: `grouped = df.groupby(["col1"]).count().reset_index(name="ccc")`

Comment: @OtoShavadze - It is expected, because `df.groupby(["col1"]).count()` return `DataFrame`

Comment: @OtoShavadze - Working well `grouped = df.groupby(["col1"])['col1'].count().reset_index(name="ccc")`