# condense multiple rows into 1 aggregated by other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select a column that is grouped by other columns and put all the values of the column in 1 row (in a list).
Input:

```
PropID    Manager    Manager_email      date
  1         A         a@aol.com       2021-02-01
  1         A         a@aol.com       2021-02-02
  1         A         a@aol.com       2021-02-03
  1         A         a@aol.com       2021-02-04
  2         B         b@aol.com       2021-02-08
  2         B         b@aol.com       2021-02-10
  2         B         b@aol.com       2021-02-12
  2         B         b@aol.com       2021-02-16
```

Desired Output:

```
PropID    Manager    Manager_email                      date
  1         A         a@aol.com       [2021-02-01,2021-02-02,2021-02-03,2021-02-04]
  2         B         b@aol.com       [2021-02-08,2021-02-10,2021-02-12,2021-02-16]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
df.groupby(['PropID','Manager','Manager_email'])['date'].agg(list)
```

Comment: this one's changing the dataframe to a series. anyway I can retain the structure in a dataframe?

Comment: try adding `.reset_index()` to the end.