# How to combine data from one row in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with sequential and frequent pattern mining. I was given this type of dataset to do the task, and I am told to make a sequence from the dataset before processing.

This is the sample data taken from dataset, in table format. The table in .csv format is available at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j1rEy4Q600y_oym23cG3m3NNWuNvIcgG/view?usp=sharing

| User | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Item 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | milk | cake | citrus |  |  |  |
| B | cheese | milk | bread | cabbage | carrot |  |
| A | tea | juice | citrus | salmon |  |  |
| B | apple | orange |  |  |  |  |
| B | cake |  |  |  |  |  |

At first, I think I have to make the csv file into Pandas Dataframe. I have no problem with that, what I want to ask is, how is it possible with dataframe to produce result like this?

Expected result 1, a group of items bought from 1 user is grouped into one tuple

| User | Transactions |
| --- | --- |
| A | (milk cake citrus)(tea juice citrus salmon) |
| B | (cheese milk bread cabbage carrot)(apple orange)(cake) |

Expected result 2, each item purchased by user is not grouped by one.

| User | Transactions |
| --- | --- |
| A | milk, cake, citrus, tea, juice, citrus, salmon, |
| B | cheese, milk, bread, cabbage, carrot, apple, orange, cake |

My question is, how to make those dataframe? I've tried a solution from this article: [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby), but it is still not successful.

Comment: You should include your attempts and what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the first result:

```
out = df.set_index('User').apply(lambda x : tuple(x[x.notna()].tolist()),axis=1).groupby(level=0).agg(list).reset_index(name='Transactions')
Out[95]: 
  User                                       Transactions
0    A  [(milk, cake, citrus), (tea, juice, citrus, sa...
1    B  [(cheese, milk, bread, cabbage, carrot), (appl...
```

For the second result which is easier than the previous one:

```
df.set_index('User').replace('',np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
Out[97]: 
User
A             milk,cake,citrus,tea,juice,citrus,salmon
B    cheese,milk,bread,cabbage,carrot,apple,orange,...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Your 1st solution includes the NaNs ;)

Comment: @mozway if the original is empty it will not

Comment: how to remove the NaN in first output?

Comment: @DionisiusPratama change this x[x.notna()]

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the second one:

```
(df.set_index('User')
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=0).apply(list)
   .rename('Transactions')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  User                                       Transactions
0    A   [milk, cake, citrus, tea, juice, citrus, salmon]
1    B  [cheese, milk, bread, cabbage, carrot, apple, ...
```

To get the first one, on just need to add a new column:

```
(df.assign(group=df.groupby('User').cumcount())
   .set_index(['User', 'group'])
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(tuple)
   .groupby(level=0).apply(list)
   .rename('Transactions')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  User                                       Transactions
0    A  [(milk, cake, citrus), (tea, juice, citrus, sa...
1    B  [(cheese, milk, bread, cabbage, carrot), (appl...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sampletable.csv')

df['Transactions'] = '(' + df[['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4','Item 5','Item 6']].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' '), axis=1) + ')'

df = df.groupby(['User'])['Transactions'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)).reset_index()

print(df)
```

output:

```
  User                                                  Transactions
0    A        (milk cake citrus)(tea juice citrus salmon)
1    B  (cheese milk bread cabbage carrot)(apple orange)(cake)
```

for the second output, use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sampletable.csv')

df['a'] = df[['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4','Item 5','Item 6']].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '), axis=1)

df = df.groupby(['User'])['a'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()

print(df)
```