# Adding same value in the same column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

Hey I would like to turn python table from

| Number | Alphabet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |

To table

| Number | Alphabet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A B C |
| 2 | A B |
| 3 | A |

I know how to add normal table using dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Alphabet': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

But not the second table

Comment: Your question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: thank you, the problem are solved with the same question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
df.groupby("Number")["Alphabet"].apply(lambda x:" ".join(x)).to_frame()
```

Comment: Why is `to_frame` necessary?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Just wanted to return a DataFrame back - `type(df.groupby("Number")["Alphabet"].apply(lambda x:" ".join(x))` is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`