# Pandas: Create a new column based on a list of other values in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

By using the following dataframe, I would like to create a new column based on a list of other values in my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)
```

The output example I would like to have is the following (Respecting the order is important):

```
    A   B   C   D  my_group
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  [D0, A0, B0]
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  [D1, A1, B1]
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  [D2, A2, B2]
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  [D3, A3, B3]
```

I saw some exaples with group by for something similar, but it is not the answer I am looking for: [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

Comment: look at the `apply()` method of a pandas dataframe [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple case of creating a **list** from defined columns

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)

df1["my_group"] = df1.loc[:,["D","A","B"]].apply(list, axis=1)
```

|  | A | B | C | D | my_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A0 | B0 | C0 | D0 | ['D0', 'A0', 'B0'] |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | ['D1', 'A1', 'B1'] |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | ['D2', 'A2', 'B2'] |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | ['D3', 'A3', 'B3'] |

Answer (score 1):

Just do `tolist`

```
df1['new'] = df1[["D","A","B"]].to_numpy().tolist()
df1
Out[424]: 
    A   B   C   D           new
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  [D0, A0, B0]
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  [D1, A1, B1]
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  [D2, A2, B2]
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  [D3, A3, B3]
```