# Sorting and splitting csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file as below:

[Weather](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBF4L.png)

I need to split csv file into multiple lists with elements that have Timestart equal. Using code below but it isnt working.

```
from numpy import e, not_equal
import pandas as pd
import csv
data= pd.read_csv("testing.csv")
t = data.sort_values('Timestart')

for x in range(len(t.Timestart)):
   for y in range(1+len(t.Timestart)):
      if t.Timestart[x] == t.Timestart[y]:
         print('Vin with same timewindow is: ',t.Vin[y])
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby help?

Comment: Does [my b/m reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630230/17850902) solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be conveniently achieved by using pandas's groupby or filtering capabilities. Looking at a solution using filtering, you can retrieve all unique column values via [`pandas.Series.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html). Using those unique values, you can filter the dataframe by the values in the column `Timestart` using the function [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a boolean expression.

In the following example, the filtered result is stored in a dict called `data`, which of course could be also a nested list or the like as well.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Reads the csv-file
df = pd.read_csv("testing.csv")

# Find all values in the Timestart-column
timestart_unique = df.Timestart.unique()

# dict indexed by unique Timestart-values
data = {}  

# Populates the dict by filtering
for t in timestart_unique:
    data[t] = df.loc[df.Timestart == t]
```

Accessing `data[1800]` will then give you something like:

```
    id  Vin     Make    Timestart   Timestop
0   1   12345   London  1800    1845
1   2   23456       NY  1800    1845
3   4   345678  London  1800    1845
```