# Many-one to one-many mapping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, data-munging

[csv jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAbJd.png)

The first column in the image is of union ministry and second column contains schemes introduced in that ministry. I want to create one-many mapping using pandas in jupyter notebook.
Output should be something like this:

{Department of Agriculture, Cooperation and Farmers' Welfare} =['Crop insurance scheme', 'Interest Subsidy for Short Term Credit to Farmers','Market Intervention Scheme and Price Support Scheme (MIS-PSS)','Pradhan Mantri Annadata Aay Sanrakshan Yojna (PM-AASHA)'#continued...]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby