# reshape data using python?

Tags: python, pandas

being new to python I am looking for some help reshaping this data, already know how to do so in excel but want a python specific solution.

[image]

I want it to be in this format.

[image]

entire dataset is 70k rows with different vc_firm_names, any help would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221675/2221001).

Comment: its a nice start, but from the looks of it, it would be a real pain to manually add group by for each of the 57k unique entries

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that. It would look something like `df = df.groupby('vc_firm_name')['investment_industry'].apply(list)`

Comment: Or `df = df.groupby('vc_firm_name')['investment_industry'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(list(x))).reset_index(name='investment_industry')` or what-have-you. There are a few ways to skin this cat that are mentioned in that q&a

Comment: oh thanks, making more sense now, thanks for the great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance, then I suggest you take a look at other methods (such as using numpy, or sorting the table):

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550516/17323241
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66018377/17323241
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22221675/17323241 (look at second comment)

Otherwise, you can do:

```
# load data from csv file
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
# aggregate
df.groupby("vc_first_name")["investment_industry"].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the original file is `"original.csv"`, and you want to save it as `"new.csv"` I would do:

```
pd.read_csv("original.csv").groupby(by=["vc_firm_name"],as_index=False).aggregate(lambda x: ','.join(x)).to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
```