# Getting data from Excel in python using pandas in dictionary format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I Have a Excel Data Like This

```
  Category  Item
  old       apple
  new       mango
  old       grape
  new       ginger
```

I need to get that data in python using pandas in the dictionary format like -

```
{'old': ['apple', 'grape'], 'new': ['mango', ginger']}
```

From one of the references from stack overflow They provide code like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Skills.xlsx", index_col=0)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)

print(df.to_dict())
```

I am getting like output like:

```
{'Skills': {'old': 'grape', 'new': 'ginger'}}
```

But I need the output like this:

```
{'Skills': {'old': ['apple', 'grape'], 'new': ['mango', ginger']}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` function after `groupby`.

```
df
```

```py
    Category      Item
0          old   apple
1          new   mango
2          old   grape
3          new  ginger
```

```py
df.groupby('Category')['Item'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

```
{'new': ['mango', 'ginger'], 'old': ['apple', 'grape']}
```

Comment: Thanks, Lazyer For your answer it is working for me. If you don't mind can you send the document link where I can found that

Comment: I recommend looking at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)!