# How to group dataframe parts of rows into list in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I saw this page, [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)
but, that's not what I need.

Let my datatable example see please.

| index | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | red |
| 1 | banana | a |
| 1 | banana | b |
| 2 | grape | wow |
| 2 | grape | that's |
| 2 | grape | great |
| 2 | grape | fruits! |
| 3 | melon | oh |
| 3 | melon | no |
| ...a lot of data... | ...a lot of data... | ... a lot of data... |

and I want to groupby ONLY index 2~3 (I need to range because my real data is hudge.)

so I want to this table

| . | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | red |
| 1 | banana | a |
| 1 | banana | b |
| 2 | grape | wow that's great grape fruits! |
| 3 | melon | oh no |
| ...a lot of data... | ...a lot of data... | ... a lot of data... |

How can I get this?

Comment: Your `index` is a column or just index? What's the output of `df.head(1).to_dict()`?

Comment: It's column. The output is {'index': {0: 0}, 'column1': {0: 'apple'}, 'column2': {0: 'red'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's filter the dataframe based on `index` column, then groupby on the filtered dataframe.

```py
m = df['index'].isin([2,3])

out = (pd.concat([df[~m],
                  (df[m].groupby('column1', as_index=False)
                   .agg({'index': 'first', 'column2': ' '.join}))], ignore_index=True)
       .sort_values('index', ignore_index=True))
```

```
print(out)

   index column1                   column2
0      0   apple                       red
1      1  banana                         a
2      1  banana                         b
3      2   grape  wow that's great fruits!
4      3   melon                     oh no
```

Comment: omg.. Thank you so much!!! and I have a question one more, How I can get this result if 'index'is not column, and real index? If you busy you can pass this question . thank you!

Comment: @now You can use `df.reset_index()` first.