# How do I create a summarized df in python using data from another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
| order_id| product_id |
| 1       | 534 |
| 1       | 234  |
| 1       |292  |
| 2       | 445 |
| 2       | 646  |
| 3       | 8734  |
```

Is there a way to create a new dataframe in which each order_id gets one row and the values in that row are all the product ids that are associated with it?

I'm a bit new to this and the only thing I could come up with was iteration which seems inefficient at best

Comment: I think whaty you're trying to do is groupby `order_id` then return the products per group as a list. If so have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530736/2981639

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to group by "order_id" and aggregate "product_id" to a list:

```py
out = df.groupby("order_id")["product_id"].agg(list).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   order_id       product_id
0         1  [534, 234, 292]
1         2       [445, 646]
2         3           [8734]
```

---

If you want string as output, not a `list`, you can do:

```py
out = (
    df.assign(vals=df["product_id"].astype(str))
    .groupby("order_id")["vals"]
    .apply(",".join)
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   order_id         vals
0         1  534,234,292
1         2      445,646
2         3         8734
```