# How to group dataframe rows into list in polars group_by

Tags: python, python-polars

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Letter': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D','D','E'],
        'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
    }
)
```

I want to group `Letter` and collect their corresponding `Value` in a List.

Related Pandas question: [How to group dataframe rows into list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/how-to-group-dataframe-rows-into-list-in-pandas-groupby)

I know pandas code will not work here:

```
df.group_by('a')['b'].apply(list)

TypeError: 'GroupBy' object is not subscriptable
```

Output will be:

```
| A      ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ B      ┆ [3, 4, 5] │
│ C      ┆ [6, 7]    │
│ D      ┆ [8, 9]    │
│ E      ┆ [10]      |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this. `maintain_order=True` is required *if you want to order of the groups to be consistent with the input data*.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Letter': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D','D','E'],
        'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
    }
)
g = df.group_by('Letter', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('Value'))
print(g)
```

This will print

```
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ Letter ┆ Value     │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ A      ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ B      ┆ [3, 4, 5] │
│ C      ┆ [6, 7]    │
│ D      ┆ [8, 9]    │
│ E      ┆ [10]      │
└────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple: If you don't specify an aggregation function in a `pl.DataFrame.group_by().agg()` construct, all values in a group will be aggregated into a list.

```py
df.group_by("Letter").agg("Value")
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ Letter ┆ Value     │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ str    ┆ list[i64] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ A      ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ B      ┆ [3, 4, 5] │
│ C      ┆ [6, 7]    │
│ D      ┆ [8, 9]    │
│ E      ┆ [10]      │
└────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM True, but that is a general `group_by` parameter not really related to the question, no?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I think this has more to do with @Palestine not putting every permutation of the rows as expected answer. Still, its good your answer has it covered! I just wont include an explanation of `maintain_order` in every single polars-related answers of mine that includes `group_by`.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM It is definitely not an anti-pattern in polars. Using `maintain_order=True` blocks polars' streaming engine (which is one of its essential features) and will degrade performance.