# Python read a file and make a nth list from the

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file that each line has 2 element like below which have nth lines:

```
1 2    
2 3   
3 4   
4 5   
1 6   
2 7   
1 8
```

I need to make a list in python.

```
list[1]=[2,6,8]
list[2]=[3,7]
list[3]=[4]
list[4]=[5]
```

How can I do?

Comment: What's the order of the elements you are trying to  store, exactly? That is, what is the pattern above that you are trying to describe.

Comment: actually i have a huge file that contains the information like the above format and i need to put in into a list. then write it into a file. I don't know how to do cos i am new to python. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4, 5], [1, 6], [2,7], [1,8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['b','c'])
print df
z = df.groupby(['b']).apply(lambda tdf:pd.Series(dict([[vv,tdf[vv].unique().tolist()] for vv in tdf if vv not in ['b']])))
z = z.sort_index()
print z
print z['c'][1]
print z['c'][2]
print z['c'][3]
print z['c'][4]
z['d'] = 0.000
z[['d']] = z[['d']].astype(float)
len_b = len(z.index)
z['d'] = float(len_b)
z['e'] = 1/z['d']
z = z[['c', 'e']]
z.to_csv('your output folder')
print z
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112443/2632856

Comment: if i want to change the last column from 1/len(list_c) into 1/(total number of b), how can i modify?

Comment: changed it to calculate 1/total number of b

Comment: yes, not calculate the len of list_c, just the total number of b for each row. (i.e. 1 [2,6] 1/4, 2 [3,7] 1/4, ...) thank you