# Group by to create unique values appearing by date, as well as non-unique values by date

Tags: python, pandas, unique, grouping

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
    app_id   subproduct date    
0    23        3        2015-05-29
1    23        4        2015-05-29     
2    25        5        2015-05-29
3    23        3        2015-05-29
4    24        7        2015-05-29
....
```

I run:

```
groupings =insightevents.groupby([insightevents['created_at_date'].dt.year,\
            insightevents['created_at_date'].dt.month,\
                        insightevents['created_at_date'].dt.week,insightevents['created_at_date'].dt.day,
            insightevents['created_at_date'].dt.dayofweek]);

inboxinsights=pd.DataFrame([groupings['app_id'].unique(),groupings['subproduct'].unique()]).transpose()
```

This gives me:

```
                    app_id    subproduct
2015 5 22 29 4     [23,24,25]  [3,4,5,7]
```

However, what I want is actually not to get just the unique values, but overall just the app_ids and sub_product loads on the day as additional columns, so:

```
               unique_ app_id  unique_subproduct subproduct app_id
2015 5 22 29 4     [23,24,25]  [3,4,5,7]         [3,3,4,5,7] [23,23,23,24,25]
```

I find that just doing:

```
inboxinsights=pd.DataFrame([groupings['app_id'].unique(), groupings['subproduct'].unique(),groupings['app_id'],groupings['subproduct']]).transpose()
```

Doesn't work and just gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just the number of unique values, that's easy:

`inboxinsights.groupby('date').agg({'app_id': 'nunique', 'subproduct': 'nunique'})`

returns:

[image: just the number of uniques]

But it looks like you want the list of what those actually are. I found [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc) helpful:

`not_unique_inboxinsights = groupby('date').agg(lambda x: tuple(x))`

[image]

And then you say want both the unique and not-unique. For that, I would make two groupby dataframes and concatenate them, like this:

`unique_inboxinsights = groupby('date').agg(lambda x: set(tuple(x)))`

[image: concatenated together]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a clarification, the set method I understand creates an unordered set of unique items. The output in my data frame is not `{3,4,5,7 }`, but `set([3, 4,5,7])`. Is this expected?

Comment: those are the same. ipython notebook just displays it differently.