# append all column in list - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to be able from a pandas Dataframe like this:

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,4])
pd.get_dummies(s)
Out[1]: 
     0    1    2    4
0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

to get one like this

```
              0             1             2             3
0  [1, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 1, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 1, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I thought about something like this but it does not work

```
df.apply(lambda y: list(y))
```

Any idea?

Thank  you.

EDIT:
Vinay87 answer work but it was not really my problem.

I was biased by my lack of knowledge and though good to simplify the problem.
What I wanted to do was to aggregate each group when applying groupby on a dataframe.
I knew only approach like the following

```
df.groupby("device_id").apply(function to turn dataframe in a dataframe with list)
```

I have been able to find a solution thanks to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc) and the answer of user2623954

Comment: It is different, the question you said it replicate create list from rows and not from columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
c = pd.Dataframe(columns = s.columns)
for column in s.columns: 
    c.set_value(0, column, list(s[column]))
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But I realized I did not explain enough my problem, sorry. I will add more explanation in the question.