# pandas groupby aggregate data across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I am using pandas to group the same time of a day (hour) and then average across all days for a diurnal cycle, in other words, apply multi-day mean on each hour. Furthermore, I want to average the data across different sources, eg. stations or countries.

Specifically, I have a dataframe **df** with pandas time index as below:

```
                     A    B    C 
2010-01-02-07:00    10   22   30
2010-01-02-08:00    12   20   NaN
2010-01-03-07:00    11   8    15
2010-01-03-08:00    10   10   9
2010-01-03-09:00    11   13   18
2010-01-05-07:00    NaN  10   16
2010-01-05-09:00    14   0    7
```

Following this post: [Can pandas groupby aggregate into a list, rather than sum, mean, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1), I can achieve my goal by extracting all the data of the same hour and concatenating them into one list. But I am still wondering if there is a more straightforward or nicer way to do this?

Here I show my code as below:

```
df['hour'] = df.index.hour        # create a new column for each time stamp
grp = df.groupby('hour').agg(lambda x: tuple(x))       # group by hour

result = grp[grp.columns[0]]          # append all the columns
for col in grp.columns:
    result = result + grp[col]

diurnal = [np.nanmean(np.array(result[hour]))  for hour in grp.index]       # average each tuple
```

And here is the output:

```
Out:
 [15.25, 12.2, 10.5]
```

Many thanks!

### ==========

I tried @Nickil's method:

```
data = {'A': [10, 12, 11, 10, 11, np.nan, 14], 'B': [22, 20, 8, 10, 13, 10, 0], 'C': [30, np.nan, 15, 9, 18, 16, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[datetime.datetime(2010,1,2,7,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,2,8,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,3,7,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,3,8,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,3,9,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,5,7,0), datetime.datetime(2010,1,5,9,0)])
df.index = df.index.hour
diurnal = df.stack().mean(level=0).tolist()
```

This is what I get:

```
Out:
 [20.666666666666668, 16.0, 11.333333333333334, 9.6666666666666661, 14.0, 13.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: You are double-counting the first column in `result`, right?

Comment: @hvwaldow oops... Thanks for pointing out! You are right, it should start from the second item in the for loop. By the way, I don't really like this way to add all the column together. Is there a better way? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simpler approach:

1) Access the hour using `.hour` attribute and assign this as the new index axis.

2) Stack the `DF` so that all columns fall under a single wholesome column. Perform `Groupby` w.r.t the hour labels (comprising of `level=0` of the multi-index) and compute the mean.

---

```
df.index = df.index.hour                 
df.stack().mean(level=0).tolist()  
Out[20]:
[15.25, 12.2, 10.5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried your method, but it returns the mean of all rows (time indices) - in this example - seven values, instead of the mean across all days?

Comment: I don't understand. But doesn't it give you the requried o/p. Maybe you can edit the post with a counter example to clear things up. This returns the mean of all the column names you have grouped by their indices hour.

Comment: I just edited my post to include your method:) do I miss something?

Comment: It works for me though. What version of `pandas/Python` do you use?

Comment: weird! I use anaconda python 2.7.12 and pandas 0.16.2, and I also turned on pylab.

Comment: Upgrade your `pandas` to the recent versions (`0.19.2`) and check.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
diurnal = [np.nanmean(g) for _, g, in df.groupby(df.index.hour)]
```

Comment: This exactly did what I want! Thank you so much. I tried to extract the data in the groupby object too. I am not familiar with the usage of underscore in the for loop, is there any introductory example about this? It looks pretty powerful.

Comment: The underscore is just a regular variable name. There is a convention to use it for "throw away variables" that are not used later.

Comment: `NumPy` is meant to provide vectorization. Using it's functions while iterating a for loop, just kills it's very purpose when there are other ways to peform the same task at hand.

Comment: I agree that using `groupby` is much likely slower than Nickil's solution. Whether that has practical impact depends. Also if you want to do other things with the groups later, clarity might beat speed.