# Plotting a graph with pandas to only display certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have created a dataframe that only contains 2 columns from another dataframe:

```
df1 = df[["BNF Chapter", "Name"]]
df1
```

This shows a dataframe with the two columns. I have performed a group by function so that for each Chapter e.g 1 it shows the names of drugs for that specific chapter

df1.groupby(['BNF Chapter','Name'])['BNF Chapter'].sum()

```
BNF Chapter  Name
1            Allantoin + Lidocaine                           4
             Aluminium hydroxide                             2
             Aluminium hydroxide + Magnesium trisilicate     2
             Alverine                                        702
21           Polihexanide                                    42
```

How can I plot this on a graph specific for Chapter 1 and have the names of the drugs on one side and the amount of times prescribed at the bottom of the graph?

I would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Any help would greatly be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Could you kindly include an example of a the values before the transformation, and how you would like it to look afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a groupby on a column(s) and still access that column -

```
df1.groupby(['BNF Chapter','Name'])['BNF Chapter'].sum()
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED do you know how I would eb able to plot this information on a graph. For example the Name of drug against how many times it has been called for one specific chapter?

Comment: @Katie Assign the result above to `g`. Then, do something like `g.plot(); plt.show()`

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have tried that but I would to plot a graph for each chapter and have the drug name on the side axis and number of times prescribed at the bottom.. Would you know how to plot this?

Comment: @Katie Yes, but I would like you to open a new question and show me 5-10 rows of your data. That would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Unfortunately I cannot post question.... 
   df1.groupby(['BNF Chapter','Name'])['BNF Chapter'].sum() 

    BNF Chapter  Name
    1            Allantoin + Lidocaine                           4
                 Aluminium hydroxide                             2
                 Aluminium hydroxide + Magnesium trisilicate     2
                 Alverine                                        702
    21           Polihexanide                                    42

Comment: @Katie Try this: `g = g.to_frame('sum').reset_index(); g.set_index('Name').plot('sum'); plt.show()`

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you, but unfortunately the left axis appears from 0 up to 100 and the bottom 0 up to 80 with just a block of blue going through the bottom half of the graph.. Ideally I would like something like https://scraperwiki.com/2015/08/the-most-prescribed-medication-for-each-bnf-chapter/

Comment: @Katie Just wait a few more minutes and post a new question. Unfortunately, I'm a bit busy now and not able to find time to help. Apologies and thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood, what you're trying to do is aggregate the matching names for a particular BNF Chapter into a set?

I'm stealing the answer from muon in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc)

```
# if list of unique items is desired, use set
df.groupby('A',as_index=False)['B'].aggregate(lambda x: set(x))

# if duplicate items are okay, use list
df.groupby('A',as_index=False)['B'].aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

Comment: Yes you are correct I want to count how many times a specific name has been called for a specific chapter.. Would you possibly know how to then plot that information in a graph?

Comment: If you just want to count the number of times a row occurs with a given chapter name, it would be df.groupby('BNF Chapter').count()

I use Zeppelin for all our visualization, so I'm afraid I can't help much there.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather have a frame with only as many rows as you have chapters, you can do this, which offers a list of names for each `BNF Chapter`.

```
df1.groupby('BNF Chapter').Name.apply(lambda x: [x])
```

**EDIT**
To your question on plotting individual drug (combinations), assuming there are not prohibitively many, you can do something like this--I note you say just for Chapter 1.

I assume this command produced the output shown in your question.
    df1.groupby(['BNF Chapter','Name'])['BNF Chapter'].sum()

If so, you can do this:

```
df1.groupby(['BNF Chapter','Name'])['BNF Chapter'].sum().loc['1'].sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh')
```

If `BNF Chapter` is not a string, remove the quotes such that `.loc['1']` becomes `.loc[1]` instead.

Comment: Thank you! Would you know how to plot a graph for each chapter and have the drug name on the side axis and number of times prescribed at the bottom.. Would you know how to plot this?

Comment: So how many times each drug appears in each chapter, or, for each chapter, how many drugs are prescribed?

Comment: unfortuanly this does display anything in my notebook

Comment: You need to add `%pylab inline` to your imports section to display graphics in the notebook with matplotlib / pylab.