# Pandas groupby, aggregate on string variable and move up empty cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with with string variables with duplicate identifiers and a lot of empty cells.

I want to group by the identifier and have all the values in one row. In case that a column has multiple entries vor one identifier, I need a new row with a suffix, so I can identify it later.

Here is my data

```
ID   name1  name2   name3   name4   name5   name6   name7   name8
Tom  sarah          mike                
Tom                                 john    john        
Gen  paul                           
Gen         sandra                      
Gen                 lara    lara    lara    lara        
Gen                                                 mike    mike
Lara bill   bill    bill                    
Lara                josh    josh            
Lara                kevin   kevin   kevin   mike    
Lara                                        devon   devon   devon
```

This is the code I have been usign so far from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc):

```
grouped = df1.groupby('ID')
df1 = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
                      name1                    name2                  name3  \
ID                                                                            
Gen   (paul, nan, nan, nan)  (nan, sandra, nan, nan)  (nan, nan, lara, nan)   
Lara  (bill, nan, nan, nan)    (bill, nan, nan, nan)  (bill, nan, nan, nan)   
Tom            (sarah, nan)               (nan, nan)             (nan, nan)   

                        name4                    name5  \
ID                                                       
Gen     (nan, nan, lara, nan)    (nan, nan, lara, nan)   
Lara  (nan, josh, kevin, nan)  (nan, josh, kevin, nan)   
Tom               (mike, nan)              (nan, john)   

                       name6                    name7                   name8  
ID                                                                             
Gen    (nan, nan, lara, nan)    (nan, nan, nan, mike)   (nan, nan, nan, mike)  
Lara  (nan, nan, kevin, nan)  (nan, nan, mike, devon)  (nan, nan, nan, devon)  
Tom              (nan, john)               (nan, nan)              (nan, nan)
```

But this is, what I actually want and I just can not figure out how to do this:

```
ID   name1  name2   name3   name3_suffixA   name3_suffixB   name4   name4_suffixA   name5   name6   name6_suffixA   name7   name8
Tom  sarah          mike                                                            john    john            
Gen  paul   sandra  lara                                    lara                    lara    lara                    mike    mike
Lara bill   bill    bill    josh            kevin           josh    kevin           kevin   mike    devon           devon   devon
```

The actuall name of the suffix doesn't matter, nor does it matter, if the additional entries are presented at the end or in between.

There are some similiar questions, I know that. But I couldn't work any of the cases/solutions and I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df.set_index('ID').stack().to_frame('c')
df = (s.set_index(s.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount().astype(str), append=True)['c']
       .unstack([1,2])
       .sort_index(level=0, axis=1))
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i,j) if j != '0' else '{}'.format(i) for i, j in df.columns]
print (df)
      name1   name2 name3 name3_1 name3_2 name4 name4_1  name5 name6 name6_1  \
ID                                                                             
Gen    paul  sandra  lara    None    None  lara    None   lara  lara    None   
Lara   bill    bill  bill    josh   kevin  josh   kevin  kevin  mike   devon   
Tom   sarah    None  mike    None    None  None    None   john  john    None   

      name7  name8  
ID                  
Gen    mike   mike  
Lara  devon  devon  
Tom    None   None
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create `Series` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - `NaN`s are removed
2. Add new level to `MultiIndex` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by first and second levels
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) by both last levels and use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for sorting `MultiIndex` in columns - only first level
4. Flatten `MultiIndex` by list comprehension with exclude `0` for first columns of names

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
                 c
ID                
Tom  name1   sarah
     name3    mike
     name5    john
     name6    john
Gen  name1    paul
     name2  sandra
     name3    lara
     name4    lara
     name5    lara
     name6    lara
     name7    mike
     name8    mike
Lara name1    bill
     name2    bill
     name3    bill
     name3    josh
     name4    josh
     name3   kevin
     name4   kevin
     name5   kevin
     name6    mike
     name6   devon
     name7   devon
     name8   devon
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna()))

L = ([pd.DataFrame(df[x].values.tolist(),
                  index=df.index,
                  columns = ['{}_{}'.format(x,i) if i != 0 
                                                 else '{}'.format(x) 
                                                 for i in range(df[x].str.len().max())]) for x in df])
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df)
      name1   name2 name3 name3_1 name3_2 name4 name4_1  name5 name6 name6_1  \
ID                                                                             
Gen    paul  sandra  lara    None    None  lara    None   lara  lara    None   
Lara   bill    bill  bill    josh   kevin  josh   kevin  kevin  mike   devon   
Tom   sarah    None  mike    None    None  None    None   john  john    None   

      name7  name8  
ID                  
Gen    mike   mike  
Lara  devon  devon  
Tom    None   None
```

**Explnation**:

1. Aggregate each column with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and convert to `list`
2. In list comprehension create `DataFrame` with each column and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The first solution works perfectly, whereas the second solution takes way longer on my actual data (just to let you know). Thank you!

Comment: @ChinChix - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit complicated than what I think , I am using `replace` + `stack` + `unstack`

```
s=df.replace('',np.nan).set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(level=1)

#gourpby here is to create the suffix , like you mention in the question  you will need then all distinct value  

s['suffix']=s['level_1']+'_'+s.groupby([s.index,s.level_1]).cumcount().astype(str)
s.set_index('suffix',append=True)[0].unstack()


suffix name1_0 name2_0 name3_0 name3_1 name3_2 name4_0 name4_1 name5_0  \
ID                                                                       
Gen       paul  sandra    lara    None    None    lara    None    lara   
Lara      bill    bill    bill    josh   kevin    josh   kevin   kevin   
Tom      sarah    None    mike    None    None    None    None    john   
suffix name6_0 name6_1 name7_0 name8_0  
ID                                      
Gen       lara    None    mike    mike  
Lara      mike   devon   devon   devon  
Tom       john    None    None    None
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution as well. I get the desired result. I upvoted the answere from jezrael, because he was faster. I wish I could mark both solutions. Thank you!